# Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++

Tags: c++, c, rotation, bit-manipulation, c++-faq

Left and right shift operators (<< and >>) are already available in C++.
However, I couldn't find out how I could perform circular shift or rotate operations.

How can operations like "Rotate Left" and "Rotate Right" be performed?

Rotating right twice here

```
Initial --> 1000 0011 0100 0010
```

should result in:

```
Final   --> 1010 0000 1101 0000
```

An example would be helpful.

(editor's note: Many common ways of expressing rotates in C suffer from undefined behaviour if the rotate count is zero, or compile to more than just a single rotate machine instruction.  This question's answer should document best practices.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Near constant time rotate that does not violate the standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387778/near-constant-time-rotate-that-does-not-violate-the-standards)

Comment: It has arrived in C++20! https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285854/895245

Answer (score 133, accepted):

See also an earlier version of [this answer on another rotate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31488147/224132) with some more details about what asm gcc/clang produce for x86.

The most compiler-friendly way to express a rotate in C and C++ that avoids any Undefined Behaviour seems to be [John Regehr's implementation](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1063).  I've adapted it to rotate by the width of the type (using fixed-width types like `uint32_t`).

```
#include <stdint.h>   // for uint32_t
#include <limits.h>   // for CHAR_BIT
// #define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

static inline uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, unsigned int c)
{
  const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n) - 1);  // assumes width is a power of 2.

  // assert ( (c<=mask) &&"rotate by type width or more");
  c &= mask;
  return (n<<c) | (n>>( (-c)&mask ));
}

static inline uint32_t rotr32 (uint32_t n, unsigned int c)
{
  const unsigned int mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n) - 1);

  // assert ( (c<=mask) &&"rotate by type width or more");
  c &= mask;
  return (n>>c) | (n<<( (-c)&mask ));
}
```

Works for any unsigned integer type, not just `uint32_t`, so you could make versions for other sizes.

**See [also a C++11 template version](https://gist.github.com/pabigot/7550454) with lots of safety checks (including a `static_assert` that the type width is a power of 2)**, which isn't the case on some 24-bit DSPs or 36-bit mainframes, for example.

I'd recommend only using the template as a back-end for wrappers with names that include the rotate width explicitly.  **Integer-promotion rules mean that `rotl_template(u16 & 0x11UL, 7)` would do a 32 or 64-bit rotate, not 16** (depending on the width of `unsigned long`).  Even `uint16_t & uint16_t` is promoted to `signed int` by C++'s integer-promotion rules, except on platforms where `int` is no wider than `uint16_t`.

---

**On x86**, this version [inlines to a single `rol r32, cl`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAArFykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn4JdpgO6bX1BIVhkdFxrXUNTdlD3b3FpYMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma24KBPiCAHQI%2B9gmGgCC61g0ITuhACLYFnIA4td3ZhsMWy8u32biYCiUDXOlx%2B60220wewOtDwLEICihayutx%2BAHo8fiCTtUIlHCwxDsCABPRII/jEHbEVB1AiYAC0aC8gh29VAuIAVDsvMECGszAB9Ag7BjcxI0%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%2B1kcputZ7puNVS20WtJTY068HOzBLq5H1M0ezlJSNBrOQ8nZKQWBdcJ2OCaWIFE5OCKdWsta16HpKIEwANycRZfzVMEIUlD6QQNSm9jMfV5blsw4sMiJ0z9RmY0TN6kzW8wzBRtG1WlPUDW%2B01UYx1cmAF1Ao0FIrMFDfmbeF%2BlWted4vkm9HXIIRZpXh6WDk%2BvYxrcHrVGhTEIB61lPr1WWZkN26Xl/WFQw0H4DqUlaEJ6nPDxCk63Xxi7XUlBPsTuz1HrdZ72loN6Pq%2B2Wzf%2BoGQfBqGYbhhGdiR/qNoe8XoklnUDhl%2Bq5YV8L9ZVhE1d9f1421nNdYPfWU4ek35bNynh993D/eIQOo8xS5Q5McPI%2BDtxY4geObvlpPt7uMa0%2BxP5XCkzbVsOvOYo0D132v/XOIUvrXyNn7AOu5aDw2HGNN%2B19P53C/hsUMYAwAPGCITCAYogEPmAAQyBe9FYQBwRdfBYpQq6jFBuMUkDw7XwjpQvBBC8BrDCiQsObgWHTidrg9A%2BCACyQg3BigAGrYHfMnFcOwDAsnpIxKcM4ryCwRGKXarp1QEAVLQ4UrMGBQhmr8DBC0xRiIkdI98MI/hwiBAiEEhjggYixGYyoSg7H/EBMCA4BjBBGLcVbZ4L4sZHERG4FEqJAmuIuJiNCeZuY2mIMGTM9ItbSjwI2bxP8qB/3IgAuBNDuEuNLsgUBhTwHHQdmdcuV8a4PTxMfWBBDRx0EcAwMUeAmCii0SQbcCDxqGxCQ5VkER8oL2HJ8UIcgdh8Iei00%2BOx%2BkEHgTUhOlsdilgbMgYc2S9m%2BgUALZAfkwaCEqKyNh6A/JuCIdOQK2lJQaPjMefYnVa7NMwCfaUBDGS0GERskZ2zVy7P2Y2H2ITRBPLQsEO8hhKQxg5ok5RRD3mp1yUVX%2BpjSwAHU8DGjwPNHpC4FRSQgDMdkCB2gNSYOgJgJJCYou5MQCZCF6jpgXhvGM8j8WEuJUhS8d4TC6g0HjAmRNJQCzEF4TAIqNDDmykhGgqgmWWRIjsUUw5wzbmQBJcCwYIhCwWAoWqLFJTJAaEwYScrbjivLldSM/LCY9NWfAwucZpXeEwPsrkkUpIECYdAtUwCImOrWr9eZndQaQ2hngJ0cMvWyrfmqENT0K7m0jeqweh9U3qlDFAf10UZ773qpAtYacK1tRug9PNSzpRJrlajWuap609UbZEkEEUoqBt4e2mVTiL4JIgNm7tAa5HNurqg/kPx7VMvDc6/ATBVnEEqZZT1A7fWSiLb2qBLa65hpahGs2gNgYxp7vG2GVAICNpTam0NR4uRtyraOrgubU1SR6hAHdJaq2U3LZW1CGga2%2Bzrd82Bjb32tvA8sm9A7ERXASTuphEc4Pes7QcHqo7kPII/j8QsHA5i0E4LEXgfgOBaFIKgTgfDLDWAigsJYTi/g8FIAQTQhG5jGhAGsXUpwACcY0HL8YrGNITFY1jSGIxwSQZGONUc4LwBQIAFXsYo4R0gcBYBIGSbzcglBdMDGALqNYfAOnRGUxACI8mJnMGIJSTgrHLRsEEJ%2BGqDn1OkCwGSIw4hPP4Fwh0AWtp5NwXaGOFYrHhSVHk8iCIiF7MeCwPJhCKJHMaaoAYYAChJF4EwOGT8NJyOsf4IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1Ced0AkIhKBrDWH0HgCIynIBzGJNUZTHBWSfjWAPI46ADSmDo5YLgXAB64o7Epyo7RqguCKqMFopBAi4KmAMBIuQ0gCDWzkFI%2B2GCTH6DEVoi3Uo1GGI0TwzQ9BtGu10BoZ2Sg7dsLdw74xXtbfOxIOYChGPLD0AhTAkWNPSdI6QcjlHqMcFoayCs/kdh8eG/9Vrlhhy4EIHmdYCR5moCtCkuWfUZi8DU1oZOpBuNrA0KcNYdP5aSC4fx%2BWsRYhjX0JwWTMP5Pw6UyptjHG5haagDARAKAic82iPpiAhmYgqMkBoBVNAm4WcoNZzztmOXpdIM5uSbnOzye85OPzlGAtLbwMF/rlGwvIAi3r6L0nKNxYS5SJLKxKOpZYOluYmWmDZdy/lwrjA9eleEKIcQVWI%2B1bUPJ3QZh9CTha5NmwcWusUqo0qNKnBBvDZKsccbmOLDTdm/NioVR0grfcPdsYG2ipvemLt471RvtJFb%2BkJvH2nvVBe3drI63e%2BdFu93i7n3ujt6OBMP772LuA%2BB5VtjuEIdEZI3Jzz8PEfI5UTsSQpx6caB6rRqwWOdg46IPSfHw4PDE95qTg2FORdzGpXSgYWfadmFOLqfjQENBrH4y4EZ05w0Gm25xk14F911C4FODMCAMkAQN/0Ew0CAiAL5030U1sCF0pw0zFwgB02lxSTlwVxQFoC4H43oWkDVyUUsy10ox13sz1wN1c3cxN27DNy914EtyCxC083t0d24F4Gd1iw63d09xS1Zl90EP9yyxyzywKyK3D1kHK2jyoNkDj3q0o10FM2awm1P3Tw60zx6xzzdDz0/FUAWyr2cAgFcHb02yKH%2BxbzyHSHbz22qDH0eyuz7y%2BzryHy8JHxnwcLn0ex8MHxCMCL6GCP6nmEWBBwSDB1X3AOh1h14C32R1EhOR2AFnINOC4CPwgFxTBlCGwC%2BgxzT2x3wEv1JwJ1vxlyvz%2BDWHJ2F3U2p1fywBiCz2k1519y4VODGjCg51iFAI0DMEAKAi5xSIUw4EF1U2fxpx4y/x/z/wAKALWBALAOkzWA3zh0wJwOp2kzMG2NSN2LmOC1SWr0kCAA) (or `rol r32, imm8`) with compilers that grok it, because the compiler knows that [x86 rotate and shift instructions](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html) mask the shift-count the same way the C source does.

Compiler support for this UB-avoiding idiom on x86, for `uint32_t x` and `unsigned int n` for variable-count shifts:

- clang: recognized for variable-count rotates since clang3.5, multiple shifts+or insns before that.
- gcc: [recognized  for variable-count rotates since gcc4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57157), multiple shifts+or insns before that.  gcc5 and later optimize away the branch and mask in the wikipedia version, too, using just a `ror` or `rol` instruction for variable counts.
- icc: [supported for variable-count rotates since ICC13 or earlier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compilers-in-inde/topic/580884).  Constant-count rotates use `shld edi,edi,7` which is slower and takes more bytes than `rol edi,7` on some CPUs (especially AMD, but also some Intel), when BMI2 isn't available for `rorx eax,edi,25` to save a MOV.
- MSVC: x86-64 CL19: Only recognized for constant-count rotates.  (The wikipedia idiom is recognized, but the branch and AND aren't optimized away).  Use the `_rotl` / `_rotr` intrinsics from `<intrin.h>` on x86 (including x86-64).

**gcc for ARM uses an `and r1, r1, #31` for variable-count rotates, but still does the actual rotate with a single instruction**: `ror r0, r0, r1`.  So gcc doesn't realize that rotate-counts are inherently modular.  As the ARM docs say, ["ROR with shift length, `n`, more than 32 is the same as ROR with shift length `n-32`"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFFEJF.html).  I think gcc gets confused here because left/right shifts on ARM saturate the count, so a shift by 32 or more will clear the register.  (Unlike x86, where shifts mask the count the same as rotates).  It probably decides it needs an AND instruction before recognizing the rotate idiom, because of how non-circular shifts work on that target.

Current x86 compilers still use an extra instruction to mask a variable count for 8 and 16-bit rotates, probably for the same reason they don't avoid the AND on ARM.  This is a missed optimization, because performance doesn't depend on the rotate count on any x86-64 CPU.  (Masking of counts was introduced with 286 for performance reasons because it handled shifts iteratively, not with constant-latency like modern CPUs.)

BTW, prefer rotate-right for variable-count rotates, to avoid making the compiler do `32-n` to implement a left rotate on architectures like ARM and MIPS that only provide a rotate-right.  (This optimizes away with compile-time-constant counts.)

Fun fact: ARM doesn't really have dedicated shift/rotate instructions, it's just MOV with the [source operand going through the barrel-shifter in ROR mode](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi14/cse30-c/lectures/PI_WI_14_CSE30_lecture_8_post.pdf): `mov r0, r0, ror r1`.  So a rotate can fold into a register-source operand for an EOR instruction or something.

---

**Make sure you use unsigned types for `n` and the return value, or else it won't be a rotate**.  (gcc for x86 targets does arithmetic right shifts, shifting in copies of the sign-bit rather than zeroes, leading to a problem when you `OR` the two shifted values together.  Right-shifts of negative signed integers is implementation-defined behaviour in C.)

Also, **make sure the shift count is an unsigned type**, because `(-n)&31` with a signed type could be one's complement or sign/magnitude, and not the same as the modular 2^n you get with unsigned or two's complement.  (See comments on Regehr's blog post).  `unsigned int` does well on every compiler I've looked at, for every width of `x`.  Some other types actually defeat the idiom-recognition for some compilers, so don't just use the same type as `x`.

---

**Some compilers provide intrinsics for rotates**, which is far better than inline-asm if the portable version doesn't generate good code on the compiler you're targeting.  There aren't cross-platform intrinsics for any compilers that I know of.  These are some of the x86 options:

- Intel documents that [`<immintrin.h>` provides `_rotl` and `_rotl64` intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&text=rotl), and same for right shift.  MSVC requires `<intrin.h>`, while gcc require `<x86intrin.h>`.  An `#ifdef` takes care of gcc vs. icc.  Clang 9.0 also has it, but before that it doesn't seem to provide them anywhere, [except in MSVC compatibility mode with `-fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=17.00`](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20160905/170179.html).  And the asm it emits for them sucks (extra masking and a CMOV).
- MSVC: [`_rotr8` and `_rotr16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy0728bz(v=vs.140).aspx).
- gcc and icc (not clang):  `<x86intrin.h>` also provides `__rolb`/`__rorb` for 8-bit rotate left/right, `__rolw`/`__rorw` (16-bit),  `__rold`/`__rord` (32-bit), `__rolq`/`__rorq` (64-bit, only defined for 64-bit targets).  For narrow rotates, the implementation uses `__builtin_ia32_rolhi` or `...qi`, but the 32 and 64-bit rotates are defined using shift/or (with no protection against UB, because the code in [`ia32intrin.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/ia32intrin.h#L146) only has to work on gcc for x86).  GNU C appears not to have any cross-platform `__builtin_rotate` functions the way it does for `__builtin_popcount` (which expands to whatever's optimal on the target platform, even if it's not a single instruction).  Most of the time you get good code from idiom-recognition.
- Clang has `__builtin_rotateleft8`, `__builtin_rotateright8`, and similar for other widths.  See [Clang's language extensions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-rotateleft) documentation. There are also builtins / intrinsics for other bit-manipulation things like `__builtin_bitreverse32` (which can compile to `rbit` on ARM / AArch64).  You can test for them with `__has_builtin`.

```
// For real use, probably use a rotate intrinsic for MSVC, or this idiom for other compilers.  This pattern of #ifdefs may be helpful
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__)

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#else
#include <x86intrin.h>  // Not just <immintrin.h> for compilers other than icc
#endif

uint32_t rotl32_x86_intrinsic(rotwidth_t x, unsigned n) {
  //return __builtin_ia32_rorhi(x, 7);  // 16-bit rotate, GNU C
  return _rotl(x, n);  // gcc, icc, msvc.  Intel-defined.
  //return __rold(x, n);  // gcc, icc.
  // can't find anything for clang
}
#endif
```

Presumably some non-x86 compilers have intrinsics, too, but let's not expand this community-wiki answer to include them all.  (Maybe do that in [the existing answer about intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776573/224132)).

---

(The old version of this answer suggested MSVC-specific inline asm (which only works for 32bit x86 code), or http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14043 for a C version.  The comments are replying to that.)

**Inline asm defeats many optimizations**, [especially MSVC-style because it forces inputs to be stored/reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323445/what-is-the-difference-between-asm-and-asm/35959859#35959859).  A carefully-written GNU C inline-asm rotate would allow the count to be an immediate operand for compile-time-constant shift counts, but it still couldn't optimize away entirely if the value to be shifted is also a compile-time constant after inlining.  **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**.

Comment: Curious, why not `bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n);` and `c &= bits - 1;` and `return ((n >> c) | (n << (bits - c)))`, which is what I’d use?

Comment: @mirabilos: Your version has UB with bits=32, count=32, in the shift by `bits - c` = `32 - 0`.  (I didn't get a ping from this because I only edited the wiki, not writing it in the first place.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `0 < count < bits` is a constant requirement of almost all CPUs and programming languages implementing rotation (sometimes `0 ≤ count < bits`, but shifting by the exact amount of bits is virtually **always** either not defined or rounds down to a nop instead of clearing the value, and rotating, well.)

Comment: @mirabilos: Right, but our goal is to write a function that feeds the shift count directly to a single asm instruction, but avoids UB on a C level for any possible shift count.  Since C doesn't have a rotate operator or function, we want to avoid UB in any of the component parts of this idiom.  We'd rather not rely on the compiler treating a C shift the same way as asm shift instructions on the target its compiling for.  (And BTW, ARM does zero the register with variable-count shifts by more than the register width, taking the count from the bottom byte of the register.  Link in the answer.)

Comment: @mirabilos: The common compilers work fine with your idiom, IIRC, but they would be allowed to make demons fly out of your nose if they wanted to with a count of `0` producing `x << 32`.  C really does say that's undefined behaviour, not just an implementation-defined result value or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes hm sure, but then just disallow that value. (Nevermind, I got your point and your answer, thanks for the verbose explanation.)

Comment: I was going to say "just use portable-snippets" but then I checked the code and it seems to (a) invoke UB for [zero shift counts](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/issues/13) and (b) [only use intrinsics on MSVC](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/issues/14). In general though having that as the compilable "reference code" for what works with all the compiler-and-platform specific hacks seems like a nice idea...

Comment: The best template version of this I ever wrote starts with `template <typename T, int width = sizeof T * CHAR_BIT>`.  But then you no longer get to assume that `width` is an exact power of 2.

Comment: In time critical code is better to use intrinsics, the short precompiled version of well known functions. It's definitely does not slow down the overall performance. When custom implementation CAN slow down even with the `__forceinline` modificator.

Comment: "assuming that uint32_t is exactly 32 bits wide, although C/C++ only guarantees that it's at least that wide." Where did you read that? Those typedefs are optional (didn't know that) if not supported by the hardware but they are guaranteed to be exactly the given size: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: @Trass3r: IDK what I was thinking when I originally wrote that about `uint32_t`.  I fixed it a while ago, only noticed your comment now.  (Unfortunately this CW answer wasn't originally posted by me so I didn't get notified.  However I am "following" it now so I'll get notified in future.)

Comment: For a while now, [clang has had `__builtin_rotateleft32`, `__builtin_rotateright32` and counterparts for other bit sizes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html). You can test for them with `__has_builtin`.

Comment: @Charphacy: Thanks.  This answer is community-wiki, you could have edited yourself, but I went ahead and added a bullet point to the list.

Answer (score 45):

**C++20 `std::rotl` and `std::rotr`**

It has arrived! http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0553r4.html and should add it to the `<bit>` header.

[cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl) that the usage will be like:

```
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t i = 0b00011101;
    std::cout << "i          = " << std::bitset<8>(i) << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotl(i,0)  = " << std::bitset<8>(std::rotl(i,0)) << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotl(i,1)  = " << std::bitset<8>(std::rotl(i,1)) << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotl(i,4)  = " << std::bitset<8>(std::rotl(i,4)) << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotl(i,9)  = " << std::bitset<8>(std::rotl(i,9)) << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotl(i,-1) = " << std::bitset<8>(std::rotl(i,-1)) << '\n';
}
```

giving output:

```
i          = 00011101
rotl(i,0)  = 00011101
rotl(i,1)  = 00111010
rotl(i,4)  = 11010001
rotl(i,9)  = 00111010
rotl(i,-1) = 10001110
```

I'll give it a try when support arrives to GCC, GCC 9.1.0 with `g++-9 -std=c++2a` still doesn't support it.

The proposal says:

> Header:
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>   // 25.5.5, rotating   
>   template<class T>
>     [[nodiscard]] constexpr T rotl(T x, int s) noexcept;
>   template<class T>
>     [[nodiscard]] constexpr T rotr(T x, int s) noexcept;
> ```

and:

> 25.5.5 Rotating [bitops.rot]
>
> In the following descriptions, let N denote `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`.
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   [[nodiscard]] constexpr T rotl(T x, int s) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Constraints: T is an unsigned integer type (3.9.1 [basic.fundamental]).
>
> Let r be s % N.
>
> Returns: If r is 0, x; if r is positive, `(x << r) | (x >> (N - r))`; if r is negative, `rotr(x, -r)`.
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   [[nodiscard]] constexpr T rotr(T x, int s) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Constraints: T is an unsigned integer type (3.9.1 [basic.fundamental]).
>   Let r be s % N.
>
> Returns: If r is 0, x; if r is positive, `(x >> r) | (x << (N - r))`; if r is negative, `rotl(x, -r)`.

A `std::popcount` was also added to count the number of 1 bits: [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/57285674#57285674)

Comment: How come bit rotations took so long to land in modern c++? Even in LLVM clang, there just have been intrinsics just a few years ago => https://reviews.llvm.org/D21457 I thought ARM had had rotate way before 2010, so they should have been there since c++11.

Comment: @sandthorn: I think the C++ and C committees have a very optimistic view of the idea that compilers should be able to recognize portable idioms (like `(x >> r) | (x << (N-r))`) and compile them to rotate instructions, so the base language doesn't need to include popcount or rotate.  Of course given that attitude, IDK why they include a `*` multiply operator for integers when you could just write shift-and-add loops everywhere.  It seems like C++20 was how long it took for someone to finally talk some sense into them and add stuff that most CPUs have, like popcnt and bit-scan; easily emulated.

Answer (score 35):

Since it's C++, use an inline function:

```
template <typename INT> 
INT rol(INT val) {
    return (val << 1) | (val >> (sizeof(INT)*CHAR_BIT-1));
}
```

C++11 variant:

```
template <typename INT> 
constexpr INT rol(INT val) {
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<INT>::value,
                  "Rotate Left only makes sense for unsigned types");
    return (val << 1) | (val >> (sizeof(INT)*CHAR_BIT-1));
}
```

Comment: Is this really a rotate left? And isn't the part with the sizeof missing an &, or something?

Comment: Fixed the roation direction, and this assumes you're shifting in zeroes on both sides (which is why you shouldn't do this for signed integer types).

Comment: Warning: This code is broken if `INT` is a signed integer and the sign is set! Test for example `rol<std::int32_t>(1 << 31)` which should flip over to 1 but actually becomes `-1` (because the sign is retained).

Comment: See http://ideone.com/aRait7 for a live example of this behavior and the suggested solution (casting the type to the equivalent unsigned type before shifting).

Comment: @Nobody: I already commented 5 years ago that you shouldn't use signed integer types. Rotation doesn't make sense on signed integer types anyway.

Comment: @MSalters: Sorry for the noise. Maybe you should edit that into the answer instead of burying it in the comments. (I wonder how it slipped by my notice, I thought I had read all comments before writing). Anyways the function itself does not warn about problems and even a seasoned programmer might oversee that he/she is passing a signed integer. The very least should be a compile-time check that the passed type is an unsigned integer.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `INT` appears to be a defined type in MSVC++, so the C++11 version won't work on windows unless you change that to something else.

Comment: Also, vs is missing `constexpr`. Sigh.

Comment: You can use `std::numeric_limits<INT>::digits` instead of `CHAR_BIT * sizeof`.  I forget if unsigned types are allowed to have unused padding (e.g. 24-bit integers stored in 32 bits), but if so then `digits` would be better.  See also https://gist.github.com/pabigot/7550454 for a version with more check for a variable-count shift.

Comment: @PeterCordes: They are. I think Cray's did (used floating point registers with padding where exponent field would be).

Comment: @fake-name '>  so the C++11 version won't work on windows unless you change that to something else...' Yeah, change that to linux. :)

Answer (score 22):

Most compilers have intrinsics for that.
Visual Studio for example [_rotr8, _rotr16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rotr8-rotr16?view=vs-2019)

Comment: wow!  way easier then the accepted answer.  

btw, for a DWORD (32-bit) use _rotr and _rotl.

Answer (score 16):

Definitively:

```
template<class T>
T ror(T x, unsigned int moves)
{
  return (x >> moves) | (x << sizeof(T)*8 - moves);
}
```

Comment: Is that `8` a misspelling of `CHAR_BIT` (which need not be exactly 8)?

Comment: Since this is the same answer as mine (except swapping right for left), Peter Cordes' comment on my answer also applies here: use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`.

Answer (score 8):

If x is an 8 bit value, you can use this:

```
x=(x>>1 | x<<7);
```

Comment: Will probably misbehave if `x` is signed.

Answer (score 7):

How abt something like this, using the standard bitset ...

```
#include <bitset> 
#include <iostream> 

template <std::size_t N> 
inline void 
rotate(std::bitset<N>& b, unsigned m) 
{ 
   b = b << m | b >> (N-m); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   std::bitset<8> b(15); 
   std::cout << b << '\n'; 
   rotate(b, 2); 
   std::cout << b << '\n'; 

   return 0;
}
```

HTH,

Comment: Need to modify it to account for shifts greater than the length of the bitset.

Comment: Added `m %= N;` to account for shifts `>= N`.

Answer (score 6):

In details you can apply the following logic.

If Bit Pattern is 33602 in Integer

```
1000 0011 0100 0010
```

and you need to Roll over with 2 right shifs then:
first make a copy of bit pattern and then left shift it: Length - RightShift
i.e. length is 16 right shift value is 2
16 - 2 = 14

After 14 times left shifting you get.

```
1000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now right shift the value 33602, 2 times as required.
You get

```
0010 0000 1101 0000
```

Now take an OR between 14 time left shifted value and 2 times right shifted value.

```
1000 0000 0000 0000
0010 0000 1101 0000
===================
1010 0000 1101 0000
===================
```

And you get your shifted rollover value. Remember bit wise operations are faster and this don't even required any loop.

Comment: Similar to the subroutines above...

b = b << m | b >> (N-m);

Comment: Shouldn't that be XOR, not OR? 1 ^ 0 = 1, 0 ^ 0 = 0, etc.  If it's OR it's not exclusive, thus it'll always be 1.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to shift right by `L` bits, and the input `x` is a number with `N` bits:

```
unsigned ror(unsigned x, int L, int N) 
{
    unsigned lsbs = x & ((1 << L) - 1);
    return (x >> L) | (lsbs << (N-L));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is following:

```
#define BitsCount( val ) ( sizeof( val ) * CHAR_BIT )
#define Shift( val, steps ) ( steps % BitsCount( val ) )
#define ROL( val, steps ) ( ( val << Shift( val, steps ) ) | ( val >> ( BitsCount( val ) - Shift( val, steps ) ) ) )
#define ROR( val, steps ) ( ( val >> Shift( val, steps ) ) | ( val << ( BitsCount( val ) - Shift( val, steps ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Will probably misbehave if `val` is signed.

Comment: An answer that uses macros for this task simply cannot be considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

Source Code
 x bit number

```
int x =8;
data =15; //input
unsigned char tmp;
for(int i =0;i<x;i++)
{
printf("Data & 1    %d\n",data&1);
printf("Data Shifted value %d\n",data>>1^(data&1)<<(x-1));
tmp = data>>1|(data&1)<<(x-1);
data = tmp;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another suggestion

```
template<class T>
inline T rotl(T x, unsigned char moves){
    unsigned char temp;
    __asm{
        mov temp, CL
        mov CL, moves
        rol x, CL
        mov CL, temp
    };
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a slightly improved version of [Dídac Pérez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c/13732181#13732181), with both directions implemented, along with a demo of these functions' usages using unsigned char and unsigned long long values. Several notes:

1. The functions are inlined for compiler optimizations
2. I used a `cout << +value` trick for tersely outputting an unsigned char numerically that I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414758/1599699
3. I recommend using the explicit `<put the type here>` syntax for clarity and safety.
4. I used unsigned char for the shiftNum parameter because of what I found in the Additional Details section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx):

> The result of a shift operation is undefined if *additive-expression* is
>   negative or if *additive-expression* is greater than or equal to the
>   number of bits in the (promoted) *shift-expression*.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline T rotateAndCarryLeft(T rotateMe, unsigned char shiftNum)
{
    static const unsigned char TBitCount = sizeof(T) * 8U;

    return (rotateMe << shiftNum) | (rotateMe >> (TBitCount - shiftNum));
}

template <typename T>
inline T rotateAndCarryRight(T rotateMe, unsigned char shiftNum)
{
    static const unsigned char TBitCount = sizeof(T) * 8U;

    return (rotateMe >> shiftNum) | (rotateMe << (TBitCount - shiftNum));
}

void main()
{
    //00010100 == (unsigned char)20U
    //00000101 == (unsigned char)5U == rotateAndCarryLeft(20U, 6U)
    //01010000 == (unsigned char)80U == rotateAndCarryRight(20U, 6U)

    cout << "unsigned char " << 20U << " rotated left by 6 bits == " << +rotateAndCarryLeft<unsigned char>(20U, 6U) << "\n";
    cout << "unsigned char " << 20U << " rotated right by 6 bits == " << +rotateAndCarryRight<unsigned char>(20U, 6U) << "\n";

    cout << "\n";


    for (unsigned char shiftNum = 0U; shiftNum <= sizeof(unsigned char) * 8U; ++shiftNum)
    {
        cout << "unsigned char " << 21U << " rotated left by " << +shiftNum << " bit(s) == " << +rotateAndCarryLeft<unsigned char>(21U, shiftNum) << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (unsigned char shiftNum = 0U; shiftNum <= sizeof(unsigned char) * 8U; ++shiftNum)
    {
        cout << "unsigned char " << 21U << " rotated right by " << +shiftNum << " bit(s) == " << +rotateAndCarryRight<unsigned char>(21U, shiftNum) << "\n";
    }


    cout << "\n";

    for (unsigned char shiftNum = 0U; shiftNum <= sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8U; ++shiftNum)
    {
        cout << "unsigned long long " << 3457347ULL << " rotated left by " << +shiftNum << " bit(s) == " << rotateAndCarryLeft<unsigned long long>(3457347ULL, shiftNum) << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (unsigned char shiftNum = 0U; shiftNum <= sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8U; ++shiftNum)
    {
        cout << "unsigned long long " << 3457347ULL << " rotated right by " << +shiftNum << " bit(s) == " << rotateAndCarryRight<unsigned long long>(3457347ULL, shiftNum) << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Overload a function:

```
unsigned int rotate_right(unsigned int x)
{
 return (x>>1 | (x&1?0x80000000:0))
}

unsigned short rotate_right(unsigned short x) { /* etc. */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--- Substituting RLC in 8051 C for speed --- Rotate left carry
Here is an example using RLC to update a serial 8 bit DAC msb first:
                               (r=DACVAL, P1.4= SDO, P1.5= SCLK)
MOV     A, r
?1:
MOV     B, #8
RLC     A
MOV     P1.4, C
CLR     P1.5
SETB    P1.5
DJNZ    B, ?1

Here is the code in 8051 C at its fastest:
sbit ACC_7  = ACC ^ 7 ; //define this at the top to access bit 7 of ACC
ACC     =   r;
B       =   8;  
do  {
P1_4    =   ACC_7;  // this assembles into mov c, acc.7  mov P1.4, c 
ACC     <<= 1;
P1_5    =   0;
P1_5    =   1;
B       --  ; 
    } while ( B!=0 );
The keil compiler will use DJNZ when a loop is written this way.
I am cheating here by using registers ACC and B in c code.
If you cannot cheat then substitute with:
P1_4    =   ( r & 128 ) ? 1 : 0 ;
r     <<=   1;
This only takes a few extra instructions.
Also, changing B for a local var char n is the same.
Keil does rotate ACC left by ADD A, ACC which is the same as multiply 2.
It only takes one extra opcode i think.
Keeping code entirely in C keeps things simpler sometimes.
```