# Rotate left in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform rotate shift in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835469/how-to-perform-rotate-shift-in-c)
>   [Bitwise rotate left function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function)

In C/C++ I have `<<` and `>>` as left shits and right shifts respectively.

To test the function of this operator, I want to find the first set bit of a number `n`, do a left shift by 1 and then do the `|` of the shifted number with the first bit I found previously.

How should I do this?

Comment: Use another variable as a buffer or use asm.

Comment: What's `n`'s type (it matters)?

Comment: It's not too hard to do this in C/C++. Though if performance matters, there are instructions to do this. But you'll need intrinsics or asm to access them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835469/how-to-perform-rotate-shift-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323633/efficient-way-of-doing-64-bit-rotate-using-32-bit-values. Somewhat similar but not a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function

Comment: @tinman not a dupe, those are unsigned numbers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The questions never ask about unsigned but the answer are such. There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c which has a C++ version with typedefs for the type.

Comment: @tinman: Only the last one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134805/bitwise-rotate-left-function is correct.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: What is the difference when doing a rotation? We are only looking at the bit pattern so signed/unsigned is not relevant (I think).

Comment: @LokiAstari what I understand by rotation is that you want the first bit moved to the end. & that can be a problem if you shift a signed value to the left.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I am not sure you will be able to predicate the value (only the bit pattern).

Comment: Rotation is not a well-defined concept on signed numbers, so one can simply treat the input as an unsigned number.

Answer (score 1):

```
long long int shiftleft(long long int number, unsigned n)    
{unsigned minusone=sizeof(long long int)*8-1;
 long long int r= number & (1LL<<minusone);//save the sign, which is the most significant bit
 long long int mask = (1LL<<minusone)-1;  //a mask to get all other bits

 return ( number<<n) | ((number & mask) >>(minusone-n)) | r; //rotate left in a loop only 63 bits 
}
```

haven't tested the code

Comment: Best practices for compiler-friendly rotates in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c.  It's far easier to just cast to unsigned for the rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a rotate left like this:

```
int n; // amount to rotate by
unsigned int d; // the positive number to rotate.
if(n < (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)))
    int x = (n << d)|(n >> ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)) - d));
```

However this will only work on a positive number. and right rotation can be accomplished like this:

```
if(n < (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)))
    int x = (n >> d)|(n << ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)) - d));
```

This also only works on positive numbers.

Comment: (n << d) can yield undefined behaviour.

Comment: You have mixed n/d up in the rotation. Change 32 to sizeof(int). Validate that n (the amount of rotation) is not larger than sizeof(int)

Comment: Yea I mean: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`

Comment: Well, "fixed" in the sense that it has code that checks a precondition. It's not universally agreed that that's a good thing. There's a great deal to be said for "don't do that".

Comment: fair enough. still not a good idea