# What's the faster way to implement the signed-to-unsigned map r(x)= 2x-1 if x>0 and r(x) = 2x otherwise

Tags: c, performance, compression, bit-manipulation

Mapping signed to unsigned integers bijectively can be done using common techniques like Two's complement. Unfortunately, they fail to map small negative integers to small numbers. For compression algorithms, we often want to preserve the absolute value of numbers as much as possible: small negative and positive numbers must be mapped to small numbers.

A popular map is r(x)= -2x-1 if x<0 and r(x) = 2x if x>=0. (A similar one is r(x) = -2x if x<=0 and 2x+1 if x>0.)

Implemented naively, this map is relatively slow. Certainly much slower than merely casting signed integers to unsigned integers (which silently applies Two's Complement).

What's the fastest way?

Comment: x > 0 instead of x ≥ 0 right?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to ask a performance question without specifying some hardware (and a compiler, for solutions in C).

Comment: @KennyTM: Assuming the signed input is 2's complement, it has to be `x >= 0` (not `x > 0` as the questioner says). Otherwise, MIN_INT and 0 both map to 0, contradicting "bijection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`silently applies Two's complement`, yes, on most mondern platforms this is just a `nop` the compiler just interprets your data differently. So this is really hard to beat.

For your comparision it would be good if you'd provide some benchmarks...

If I am not mistaken `2 * abs(x) + signbit` can be done with a cyclic left shift of the bits. So if your platform has such an instruction, this should be easy to implement with inline assembler and should result in just one instruction at the end.

**Edit:** I was mistaken, this simple thing would only work with *sign and value* representation of negative numbers.

For two's complement you'd have to negate the result of the rotation if the input had been negative. Something like

```
inline uint64_t rotateL(uint64_t x) {
  asm ("rolq %0" : "=r" (x) : "r" (x));
  return x;
}

inline uint64_t value(uint64_t x) {
  uint64_t ret = rotateL(x);
  return (ret % UINT64_C(2))
    ? -ret
    : ret;
}
```

I looked into the assembler that it produced by gcc. Looks quite good, has just 5 instructions

```
rolq    %rax
movq    %rax, %rdx
negq    %rdx
testb   $1, %al
cmovne  %rdx, %rax
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken cyclic left shift of 0xFF produces 0xFF and that's not what Daniel wants

Comment: @Maciej: right would only work for the `sign and magnitude` representation. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You don't need inline asm for rotates; compilers recognize the `x<<1 | x>>63` rotate idiom.  [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508)

Answer (score 1):

If you operate on bytes lookup table must be the fastest.

For larger integers, CMOV-based implementation would be decent. 
You can also utilize SSE instructions here.

Comment: Any example with SSE instructions?

Comment: @DanielLemire: With AVX-512, `vprold` by 1, and `vpabsd` for absolute value.  [SIMD: Bit-pack signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67088336)

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation supports arithmetic right-shift of signed values, try this:

```
#define MAP(x) ((x)<<1 ^ (x)>>sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT-1)
```

For implementations which don't have signed right-shift, you can use:

```
#define RSHIFT(x,n) ((x)>>n | \
  (-(1 & (x)>>sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT-1))<<sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT-1-n<<1))
```

(You should check this for correctness...)