# Bit Shifting in Place

Tags: c++, bit, shift

I was just wondering if there was a way to bit shift a number "in place"?
I've googled exactly that, and I can't find anything that pertains to what I want to do.
Say I have the number 0b01001101, and I want to shift it twice to the right "in place", appending any numbers that fall off to the beginning. So it would look like 0b01010011. 
Is there any function in c++ that would allow me to bit shift left or right like that?

Comment: Is the term "circular shift" what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c And also you can google that term

Comment: Okay, how would I go about making my own? Should i just AND it with 1, if result is 1, shift right 1 and then OR it with 255 (or however large the binary is)? And similar method for left shift?

Comment: @Yuf Yes, I think that is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: Look up "rotate with carry".  Most processors have an instruction that performs this.

Comment: To nitpick, the common difference between a shift and a rotate is that a rotate involves carry (from a previous operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement a [rotational shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift)

Here's a templatized version that should work with all types of ints (including shorts, chars, ints, and unsigned/signed alike).

```
template<class T>
T rotate_shift_right(T x, int shift)
{
    if ((shift > 0) && (shift < (sizeof(x)*8)))
    {
        x = ((unsigned)x >> shift) | (x << (sizeof(x) * 8 - shift));
    }
    return x;
}

template<class T>
T rotate_shift_left(T x, int shift)
{
    if ((shift > 0) && (shift < (sizeof(x)*8)))
    {
        x = (x << shift) | (((unsigned)x) >> (sizeof(x) * 8 - shift));
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the assembly instruction ror and getting the carry flag's value each time should do the work.

```
int rotate(int x, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        __asm {
            ror   x, 1            ; rotate and store limit bit in cf
            lahf                  ; get part of flags in ah
            and   ah, 1           ; get only the cf
            shl   eax, 31         ; put it at the end
            and   x, eax          ; and store in x
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: While I'm impressed by the mad-crazy assembly skills, I'd imagine that this code would add enormous portability problems.

Comment: @Stargazer712: that's the other side of the medal :P it should work on every intel's processor though

Comment: It is not only portability, but this is probably less efficient than the C or C++ construct.

Answer (score 1):

Write one yourself, I think it's not hard.

First store the right two bits,and then do the bit shift.Finally fill the left two bits with the stored bits.

Comment: I think I will just do this, since I need to implement it in both Python and C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think shifting it and then anding the last byte onto the beginning should work.

Comment: While this Q&A has seemingly run its course you should probably edit your answer to use "or'ing" as "anding" the last byte is the wrong operation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should create your custom one

Comment: this is true, though minimalistic, and answers the question

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @rhalbersma well, if I read again the question I think my post is actually an answer. Maybe too short (guess that's why 2 downvotes) but is correct.

Comment: @Saphrosit it is a "strict subsequence" of the accepted answer (because you don't specify how to write one), and doesn't add anything. If you self-delete, you regain your downvotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented as vendor-specific extensions. For MSVC, you can use [_rotl8, _rotl16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5e2f3sc%28VS.80%29.aspx) (or `_rotr*` for rotating to the right). Not sure about GCC, but you can always drop to assembly and use the `rol` or `ror`.