# Problem with Bitwise Barrel Shift Rotate left and right in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, rotation, bit-shift

In C++ I have code like this.

```
    static UInt32 rol(UInt32 value, UInt32 bits)
    {
        bits &= 31;
        return ((value << bits) | (value >> (32 - bits)));
    }

    static UInt32 ror(UInt32 value, UInt32 bits)
    {
        bits &= 31;
        return ((value >> bits) | (value << (32 - bits)));
    }
```

how would it look in C#? I think the same exact way.. only problem

> Error 2   Operator '>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'uint'
>   Error   3   Operator '>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'uint'
>   Error   1   Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'uint'
>   Error   4   Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'uint'

Comment: For the record: best-practices for expressing rotates in a compiler-friendly way, avoiding C undefined behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c.  When `bits == 0`, this code will shift the 32b `value` by 32bits.  Hopefully that's legal in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `int` type for the right side variable in shift operators.

Comment: wouldn't that mess with `bits &= 31;` logic though? must I create another variable after that? if I just change `UInt32 bits` to `int bits` fixes everything but will that `bits AND 31` logic ever mess up?

Comment: You can replace `bits &= 31` by `bits %= 32`.

Comment: Why the use of Contract? is that to surpass exceptions? I cannot find that library in my .NET framework.

Comment: It's just a way to write `if then throw` expression in one string, plus - you have static checking with code contracts library. You can learn about it at [microsoft site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/)

Comment: @SSpoke: no, the result of `var &= 31;` isn't affected by signedness.  Signedness changes the meaning of the MSB only.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cast the right side of the bitshift operator to int. If you cast like `(int)(32 - bits)`, it should not affect your intended purpose. The right side is just expecting an int, probably because it's simpler that way and highly unlikely you'll ever want to shift more than 2 billion bits.

Comment: ya screw it I picked your solution.. easier fix.. `return ((value << (int)bits) | (value >> (int)(32 - bits)));` and `return ((value >> (int)bits) | (value << (int)(32 - bits)));`

Answer (score 1):

The right operand must be always type int.

```
 int x << int bits
 uint x << int bits
 long x << int bits
 ulong x << int bits
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some parentheses and it works:

```
byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
UInt32 crc32 = ((UInt32)msg.Data[3] << 24) +
    ((UInt32)msg.Data[2] << 16) +
    ((UInt32)msg.Data[1] << 8) +
    msg.Data[0];
```