# How does the x86 ROR instruction works?

Tags: assembly, x86

My `EAX` register contains the `xxxxxx9D` value and I have the following assembly code:

```
C0C8 14 --> ROR AL,14
```

To me, it means that the last 8 bits of the `EAX`'s 32 bits value are rotated bitwise by 14 mod 8 = 6 positions

```
0x9D = b1001 1101
```

will be transformed into

```
b0111 0110 = 0x76
```

However, OllyDbg tells me that `EAX = xxxxxxD9`, which means EAX has been rotated bitwise by 4 bits!

Where am I wrong?

Comment: That's 14 hex which is 20 decimal.

Comment: For the record: best-practices for expressing rotates in a compiler-friendly way, avoiding undefined behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c.  That answer has code that will get gcc and clang to produce a single `ror` instruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to rotate an 8-bit register by 20 positions.  That's a bit much, rotating by 8 produces the same value.  Rotating by 9 is the same as rotating by 1.  Etcetera.  The processor will thus rotate by 20 mod 8 = 4 positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What was my error?
Confusing h14 = d20 with d14......

Yes, 20 mod 8 produces 4
What a fool I am sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

Post your complete code, with this:

```
mov     al,$9d
ror     al,14
```

I get 76 as expected.

**Edit** If you rotate by $14 positions, you will get d9.