# Shift Operator (<<) Explanation

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me what this is doing:

```
    System.out.println(1 << val);
```

for val = 17, the answer is coming as: 131072

Comment: can you explain related to the example given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary representation of 1 is `00000000000000000000000000000001`

`1 << 17` will move the last `1` in the binary representation 17 places left, which will result in `0000000000000100000000000000000`, which when converted back to decimal results is 131072

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

This is a bitwise operation. Basically you are shifting the bits that originally made up your variable, and then those bits now represent a new number.

In this case, you shift to the left a few spots, which suddenly adds a lot more bits into your number... adding a greater value to it.

[How do shift operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-does-shift-operators-work-in-java)