# What is the result of these type conversions and why?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, primitive-types

I have some problems understanding what are the types after each

```
 System.out.println();
```

line in this Java code.
Right now I am getting errors at line 4 and the rest of the code does not run, can determine what is the problem? 
Can somebody explain to me what of what type is the result and why? I guess you don't even have to run the code, it just asks for some basic Java knowledge, that I do not have :(
From what I understand

```
         System.out.println ((1<<1) << 2);
```

delivers 8... but then again, why?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s= {"a", "2.0", "3", "eip"};
    System.out.println (s[7/3]);
    System.out.println (Integer.parseInt(s[1])*3.0f);
    System.out.println ((1<<1) << 2);
    System.out.println (s[s.length-1].equals("EIP"));
    System.out.println (Double.parseDouble(s[2]+1) == Integer.parseInt(s[1]));
    System.out.println (1==0|| ! (false & !true));
    }}
```

Comment: Too many questions in one thread. Ask one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`s[1]` == > 2.0

2.0 is decimal/double hence can not be converted into `int` using `Integer.parseInt(s[1])`.

You need  `Double.parseDouble(s[1])`.

`(1<<1) << 2` using shifting operator. Study here about this [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Answer (score 0):

For

```
System.out.println ((1<<1) << 2);
```

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-does-shift-operators-work-in-java) for left shift explanation.

Instead of this:

```
System.out.println (s[s.length-1].equals("EIP"));
```

try:

```
System.out.println (s[s.length-1].equalsIgnoreCase("EIP"));
```