# What is my code for inverting all the bits in a 32 bit integer producing the incorrect output?

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, bit-manipulation

This is from  a hacker rank practice problem(not a competition) https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits. Just doing this for practice.
The problem just asks you to take a set number for 32 bit integers and for each one, invert all the bits inside that integer and print out the result
Here's my code so far

```
 static long getComplement(long c) {
    long complement = 0;
    for(int k = 31; k >= 0 ; k --) {
        long evaluateBit = c >> k;
        if(evaluateBit == 1) {
            evaluateBit = 0;
        }  else {
            evaluateBit = 1;
        }
        complement += evaluateBit << k;
     }
    return complement;
}
```

Here is my high level pseudo code thinking. I will evaluate every bit in the integer. To do this, I have to right shift the bit by its position(something that was at position 31 would have to be right shifted by 31 to get to position 0 so I can evaluate it). That's why my loop started at 31 and ends at 0. And then once i get the bit at that position, I will invert it with a conditional statement and then left shift the result by the same result. I will finally add it to the sum I am keeping (what was 0 * 2 ^ 31 will consist of 1 * 2 ^ 31)

Does anyone see any problems with my pseudo code?

There has to be a problem because when I tried running the code in my IDE, here is what I got when I debugged the code [image]

I tried doing a test run with a input of 0.
After my first run(k=31), I somehow get a negative number. Does anyone know what the problem is or how I can fix this?

I made sure that I used the right shift operators as well, from [How do shift operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-do-shift-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: Someone please explain the downvote? This explicitly follows a specific programming problem from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first iteration changes the left most bit from 0 to 1. This is the sign bit, so of course you got a negative number.

EDIT :

change

```
evaluateBit = (c >> k);
```

to

```
evaluateBit = (c >> k) & 1;
```

In order for evaluateBit to really contain the value of a single bit.

Comment: For input of 0 to this problem, I am supposed to get 4294967295
, not -1.

Comment: @committedandroider That's because the assignment specifically asks to use unsigned integers but you're using signed integers.

Comment: yeah but from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java, java has no unsigned integers

Comment: @Juhana  you guys were right. It was due to the data type. I changed all the data types in that method to long so this will no longer be an issue. But I am still getting the incorrect output for input of 2147483647. The expected is 2147483648 but I am getting 3221225471. Do guys see what the issue is?

Comment: @committedandroider 4294967295 is not within the range of int, so you can't get that output for a 0 input.

Comment: @Eran Thanks I changed that, but do you know why that code segment is getting the wrong output for input of 2147483647? This would take way too long to debug for me.

Comment: @Eran the issue was if I had something like 100(1).....0 and I were to right shift everything by 28 to evaluate that bit, I would get 0....1001, which I wanted to into this block if(evaluateBit == 1) but it actually went into the else block because 1001 is not 1?

Comment: @committedandroider yes