# Left shift on Byte and Int in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. So, I want to understand the working behind it.

> ```
> int one_int = 1; 
> byte one = 1;
> one <<= 7;
> one_int <<= 7;
> System.out.println(one_int); //Output is 128 
> System.out.println(one); //Output is -128
> ```
>
> Why the output of left shift on int is 128 and on byte is -128?

Comment: first bit of byte is sign bit. so , 1000 0000 => -128 , but 8th bit of integer is just a part of integer. like, 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 000. so, integer sign bit is different with byte's one from looking right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do shift operators work in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-do-shift-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: @vatsalmevada I don't think this is a good duplicate, because it does not address the sign bit specifically.

Comment: `(byte) 128 == -128`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java

- int consist 32 bits
- byte consist 8 bits

When you shift the byte 7 times left:

00000001 -> 10000000

When you shift the int 7 times left:

00000000000000000000000000000001 -> 00000000000000000000000010000000

Because they are both used in order to present signed and unsigned number, we use the [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) operation.

this means that the first bit (MSB) represents the sign of the number (0 for +, 1 for -).

Answer (score 0):

Both shift operations produce the same binary value of 10000000<sub>2</sub>. The difference is in interpretation of that value's most significant bit.

The most significant bit of a signed integer number determines if the number is positive (zero) or negative (one).

- `int` is a 32-bit type, so its most significant bit is zero, hence 10000000<sub>2</sub> is interpreted as a positive 128
- 'byte' is an 8-bit type, so its most significant bit is one, hence 10000000<sub>2</sub> is interpreted as a negative -128

Comment: @VishalSharma You are welcome. If this answers your question, please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the check mark next to it.