# How should i solve this error:bad operand types for binary operator '&&'

Tags: java, if-statement

I don't know what's wrong but this code is giving me this  **error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'**

```
  if((n%2==0) && (n>>6) && (n<<20))
{

          ans = "Not Weird";
      }
```

Comment: What do you think `n>>6` and `n<<20` do? They shift bits. They don't resolve to a boolean to be checked for a true or false value. You may be thinking of `>` and `<`.

Comment: Thanks it worked !

Answer (score 1):

Greater than is just `>`, not `>>`, which is a shift operator. Same for less than and `<` vs `<<`.

The shift operator returns an integral type and `&&` expects both sides to be of type boolean. For more information on the shift operators, see this question: [How do shift operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-do-shift-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`>>` and `<<` are bitwise operators. They evaluate to integral types and Java does not convert integral types implicitly to `boolean` types, which are required for `&&` arguments and the `if` condition.

So you ought to rewrite to

```
if (n > 6 && n < 20 && n % 2 == 0)
```

I've taken the liberty of removing the superfluous parentheses and re-ordered the statements so the computationally cheaper `>` and `<` are evaluated first, and the more expensive `%` only if necessary. It's a micro-optimisation but demonstrates to readers of your code that you know what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

Here >> is a signed shift right operator. For example

```
  int x = -4;
  System.out.println(x>>1);   
  int y = 4;
  System.out.println(y>>1);
```

will give you

```
-2
2
```

The same applies for shift Left  << operator.

You want to check greater than or less than. So for that purpose you need '>' or '<' operator.
so the correct conditional checking will be like

```
  if((n%2==0) && (n>6) && (n<20)) {
       ans = "Not Weird" 
   }
```

Comment: Not the down-voter, but looking at this answer and other answers you've given, you may give the correct code, but very little to no explanation. Elaborating on why the OP is getting an error, or explaining your correction, would greatly reduce the likelihood of people down-voting your answers.

Comment: @AntonH Thanks for your advice

Comment: Not a downvoter either (from the low quality posts review queue here): A good answer is not just code, please elaborate with what this is, what is different from the original, what was wrong and **why** it was wrong