# When we use this type of syntax :- int a[]=new int[3<<1];

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

Actually I know the declaration of array in java but here I am unable to understand the use of this syntax:

```
int a[] = new int[3 << 1];
```

In place of a size for the array, here `<<` this symbol is used for?

Comment: Try printing `a.length` and you will see `6` although I don't know why would you want to do it instead of just `6`. `<<` is called signed left-shift operator. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: It is also in C compatible style: `int[] a = new int[3 << 1];` you will find more often. `3 << 1` (6) maybe stems from a 2x3 matrix being stored in a linear vector of 6 elements. Check the rest of the code

Comment: how you people found the 6 i want the process which u used

Comment: `3` is `11b` in binary, shift it by `1` bit to the left, and you get `110b` or `6` decimal.

Comment: @SUCHITRAGIRI Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/1410303) to know more about bit shift operators in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is the left shift operator and belongs to the [bitwise and bit shift operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). For a detailed explanation of how each bitwise and bit shift operator works, please refer to [this answer by @DerekPark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/4216641). Thus, `3 << 1` is an arthmetic expression that gets evaluated before the array is created. `3 << 1` evaluates to `6`, thus an `int[]` of size `6` gets created.

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YUaeVg)

Comment: Can you explain me how you got the answer which is 6 , i want the explanation elaborately!

Comment: @SUCHITRAGIRI please read the site I have linked. It explains what the operator does. It basicalls shifts the bit pattern of `3` (which is `0...011` in base2) `1` to the left, filling up a `0` on the right. Thus `0...011` becomes `0...0110`, which, when converted to base10, is `6`.

Comment: @SUCHITRAGIRI I updated my answer and added a linkt to another answer, explaining all bitwise and bit shift operations.

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` symbol is known as the "left shift operator."  As you can probably guess, it gets its name from shifting bit positions to the left.

There's a good example posted by another user at the following:

[How do shift operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910913/how-do-shift-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Right shift and left shift operators shift your number to the right of left in their binary representation. If you left shift by one the number 3 `3<<1` this would mean that:

The binary for 3 which is `011` gets shifted to the left(basically a 0 is added in the front) `0110` and now your number is 6.

The opposite thing would happen with right shift: If you have the number 3 `011` and you right shift it by 1 `3>>1`  the first bit will get chopped off `01` and you'll end up with the number 1.

Shift operators are useful for multiplying or dividing by powers of 2, and it's a bit faster than just saying 3*2.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is the bitwise left shift operator and is often used for efficiently multiplying for specific powers of two, as bitwise operators tend to be faster. `x << n` is usually equivalent to `x*2n`, except for cases involving int overflow.

`3` in binary is represented as `11` and after shifting to the left by one, it becomes `110`, which is `6` in decimal. It can be seen intuitively that shifting by `n` places to the left is equivalent to multiplying by two `n` times, as each shift adds a binary digit to the right, which increases the value of every other digit by a factor of 2.

Comment: Actually 3 is just `11` and 6 is `110`

Comment: @JeroSquartini Thanks. I have no idea why I wrote that.

Comment: No problem. If any of these answers solved your issue, consider accepting it by ticking the check mark beside it.