# bitwise shift in uint

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

```
uint number = 0x418  in bits : 0000010000011000
uint number1 = 0x8041 in bits: 1000000001000001
uint number2 = 0x1804 in bits: 0001100000000100
```

I cannot get 0x8041 with

```
   number >> 4;
```

or

```
   (number >> 4) & 0xffff;
```

How I can get 0x8041 and 0x1804 from 0x418 with shift?

**SOLUTION**

```
(number >> nbits) | (number << (16 - nbits))
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c for best practices for compiler-friendly rotates that guard against problems when the count is 0 or greater than the type width.  Should work equally well in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not have a bitwise *rotate* operator - bits *shifted* past the right end just fall off and vanish. What you can do to solve this is

`(number >> nbits) | (number << (32 - nbits))`

which will right-rotate a 32-bit unsigned integer by `nbits` bits.

Comment: what has this question to do with rotation?

Comment: @Aniket Well, seeing the OP's edit to the question, this answer was exactly what he was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is typically known as Rotation, not Shifting. In assembly (x86), this is exposed via ROR and ROL instructions.

I'm not aware of a bitwise operator available in C# to do this, but the algorithm is simple enough:

```
value = value & 0x1 ? (1 << Marshal.SizeOf(value) * 8 - 1) | (value >> 1) : ( value >> 1);
```