# Where are the native jvm files (Object.c, Class.c) compiled/linked to?

Tags: java, jvm, native

The title explains it all.
I was thinking looking into the jvm one might find a java/lang/Object.so (and same for Class... and any other java class that has native), or equivalent, but it's nowhere to be found. I tried to look into the compilation scripts for the OpenJDK but couldn't make sense of them.

Answer: libjava.so

A relevant link: http://fuseyism.com/openjdk/cvmi/java2vm.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's the Java code for the Java class library provided by `jre/lib/rt.jar`. It is not compiled into native code ahead-of-time, but just-in-time by the Hotspot compiler (if executed a threshold number of times, otherwise an interpreter is used) during JVM startup/execution.

There's an optimization called `Class Data Sharing` that parses classes from `rt.jar` and stores the internal in-memory class representation used by the JVM in `jre/lib/[arch]/[type]/classes.jsa` so that the classes covered do not have to be processed again and again. This file can be shared by multiple JVM instances by means of memory mapping.

Then there's `jre/lib/[arch]/[type]/libjvm.so`, which contains the actual JVM code including the Hotspot compiler.

Lastly, there are a number of additional libraries in `jre/lib/[arch]` that contain JNI implementations required by the Java class library. For example, `libjava.so` contains various JNI exports for the `java.lang` and `java.io` packages, amonst others.

With Java 9, the Java module system was introduced, which also affected `rt.jar`. `rt.jar` was replaced with corresponding modules residing in `jmods`. Additionally, the architecture was dropped from internal paths and the `jre` subdirectory does not exist anymore.

Java 9 also introduced an experimental ahead-of-time compiler that could be used to precompile the Java class library, at least in theory. AFAIK, it's still experimental as of Java 14.

Comment: Side note: `rt.jar` was divided into a number of packages starting with Java 9.  They're located in the `jmods` directory; for example, `jmods/java.base.jmod` contains most of the standard library.

Comment: @Powerlord Thanks for the reminder, I updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: Thank you. I guess libjava.so is the answer I was looking for then.

Comment: Some specific methods from JRE are not compiled by JIT, but  at runtime are replaced with native implementations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892322/when-will-jvm-use-intrinsics

Comment: @rkosegi Yes, but replacing those method calls with equivalent instructions is still done by the JIT. Not all methods will be compiled by the JIT as a general principle of Hotspot, the implementation starts off with interpretation.