# How to rotate the bits of given number?

Tags: c++, c, rotation, bit

How do I rotate the bits of given number, input number of rotations, at runtime?

For example:

```
binary:    10000000000000000000000000001011
rotations: 3 times right
result:    01110000000000000000000000000001
```

Similarly:

```
binary     10000000000000000000000000001011
rotations: 4 times left
result:    00000000000000000000000010111000
```

Below is my code to swap, but I couldn't find the logic to rotate the bits.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,bitleft,bitright,i,j;
    printf("enter ur number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=31,j=0;i>j;i--,j++) 
    {
        bitleft=num>>i&1;  //storing bits in integer from left
        bitright=num>>j&1;  //storing bits in integer from right
        if(bitleft!=bitright) // checking if bits are not similarly
        {
            num=num^1<<i; // not similar then complement
            num=num^1<<j;

        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(j=31;j>=0;j--)  // loop to print swapped bits
    {
        if(num&1<<j)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    } 
}
```

Comment: @user3859409 What does this words "no of rotations ,at runtime" mean?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift#Implementing_circular_shifts) provides a nice clean implementation

Comment: DR; Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c

Comment: To rotate `num` to the left by `k` bits, write `(num << k) | (num >> (sizeof(num)*CHAR_BIT - k))`.

Comment: Use `asm("...")` if possible.

Comment: @fred Larson i know it is asked before but answer are with built in function i don't want to use any built in function and this was the qustion asked in google interview ?

Comment: @user3859409: There are 13 answers there. Some use inline asm, some use intrinsic functions, some are plain code snippets. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T rol_(T value, int count) {
    return (value << count) | (value >> (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT - count));
}

template <typename T>
T ror_(T value, int count) {
    return (value >> count) | (value << (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT - count));
}

int main() {
    unsigned int a = 0x8000000B; // 10000000000000000000000000001011 in binary
    std::cout << "A = 0x" << std::hex << a << ", ror(A, 3) = 0x" << ror_(a, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A = 0x" << std::hex << a << ", rol(A, 3) = 0x" << rol_(a, 3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `(value << count)` in **rol** and `(value >> count)` in **ror** set the high bits in **rol** and the lower bits in **ror**. The other bits fall away.
- `(value >> (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT - count))` in **rol** and `(value << (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT - count))` in **ror** set the bits that fall away in the previous operation.

Example (assuming types of 32bits):

```
binary:               10000000000000000000000000001011
rotations: 3 times right
(value >> 3):         00010000000000000000000000000001
(value << (32 - 3)):  01100000000000000000000000000000
------------------------------------------------------
                      01110000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: i was looking for solution without using any inbuilt function or any library

Comment: Updated the code using sizeof(T) and CHAR_BIT.