# Rotating "X" left by 4 bits

Tags: bitwise-operators

```
/** The result of rotating X left by 4 bits. To rotate left means
 * that the 4 most significant bits become the 4 least significant  
 * and all other bits move left by 4. For example,  
 * rotl4(0x12345678) is 0x23456781. */
  int rotl4(int x) {
     return ;
  }
```

I am trying to figure out how to shift the 4 most significant bits but I am not sure on how would you rotate them to the end
-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you search for is [Circular shift operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c)

For now, you can try this:

```
int rotl4(int x) {
    unsigned int y = x;
    return ((y>>28)|(y<<4));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain your reasoning?

Comment: @Edwan most of the bits go 4 to the left, the top 4 have to go all the way to the right. Probably sounds obvious, but that's just what the code is saying too.