# Bitwise Rotate Right

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I am trying to convert this C function into Python;

```
typedef unsigned long var;
    /* Bit rotate rightwards */
    var ror(var v,unsigned int bits) {
        return (v>>bits)|(v<<(8*sizeof(var)-bits));
    }
```

I have tried Googling for some solutions, but I can't seem to get any of them to give the same results as the one here.

This is one solution I have found from another program;

```
def mask1(n):
   """Return a bitmask of length n (suitable for masking against an
      int to coerce the size to a given length)
   """
   if n >= 0:
       return 2**n - 1
   else:
       return 0

def ror(n, rotations=1, width=8):
    """Return a given number of bitwise right rotations of an integer n,
       for a given bit field width.
    """
    rotations %= width
    if rotations < 1:
        return n
    n &= mask1(width)
    return (n >> rotations) | ((n << (8 * width - rotations)))
```

I am trying to btishift `key = 0xf0f0f0f0f123456`. The C code gives `000000000f0f0f12` when it is called with; `ror(key, 8 << 1)` and Python gives; `0x0f0f0f0f0f123456` (the original input!)

Comment: Why are you passing in `8 << 1`for the rotations then? That's larger than `width`, so you end up with 0 rotations (`16 % 8` is 0).

Comment: It's in a loop up to 3. So it will rotations will be `8 << 0`, `8<<1`, `8<<2`.

Comment: All those are larger than `width` *and* multiples of `width`, so `rotations %= width` will always be `0`.

Comment: I understand that. If I change `width` I get results that are still not comparable to that of the C output.

Comment: The C output looks like a rotation by 16 bits, with a mask of 32 bits. I have no idea why you are using `rotations %= width` at all here.

Comment: Martijn Peters already explained why Python gives the original input (the rotation is a multiple of the width). So why place the bounty? If there is another example which gives the wrong answer (where the rotation is not a multiple of the width), edit the question to show it.

Comment: For the record: best-practices rotates in C:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c

Answer (score 5):

Your C output doesn't match the function that you provided. That is presumably because you are not printing it correctly. This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t ror(uint64_t v, unsigned int bits) 
{
    return (v>>bits) | (v<<(8*sizeof(uint64_t)-bits));
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%llx\n", ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 4));
    printf("%llx\n", ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 8));
    printf("%llx\n", ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 12));
    printf("%llx\n", ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 16));
    return 0;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
f0123456789abcde
ef0123456789abcd
def0123456789abc
cdef0123456789ab
```

To produce an ror function in Python I refer you to this excellent article: http://www.falatic.com/index.php/108/python-and-bitwise-rotation

This Python 2 code produces the same output as the C program above:

```
ror = lambda val, r_bits, max_bits: \
    ((val & (2**max_bits-1)) >> r_bits%max_bits) | \
    (val << (max_bits-(r_bits%max_bits)) & (2**max_bits-1))

print "%x" % ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 4, 64)
print "%x" % ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 8, 64)
print "%x" % ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 12, 64)
print "%x" % ror(0x0123456789abcdef, 16, 64)
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way I've found in Python:
(note this works only with integers as inputs)

```
def ror(n,rotations,width):
    return (2**width-1)&(n>>rotations|n<<(width-rotations))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different problems in your question.

### C part :

You use a value of key that is a 64 bits value (`0x0f0f0f0f0f123456`), but the output shows that for you compiler unsigned long is only 32 bits wide. So what C code does is rotating the 32 bits value `0x0f123456` 16 times giving `0x34560f12`

If you had used `unsigned long long` (assuming it is 64 bits on your architecture as it is on mine), you would have got `0x34560f0f0f0f0f12` (rotation 16 times of a 64 bits)

### Python part :

The definition of width between mask1 and ror is not consistent. `mask1` takes a width in bits, where ror takes a width in bytes and one byte = 8 bits.

The `ror` function should be :

```
def ror(n, rotations=1, width=8):
    """Return a given number of bitwise right rotations of an integer n,
       for a given bit field width.
    """
    rotations %= width * 8  #  width bytes give 8*bytes bits
    if rotations < 1:
        return n
    mask = mask1(8 * width)  # store the mask
    n &= mask
    return (n >> rotations) | ((n << (8 * width - rotations)) & mask)  # apply the mask to result
```

That way with `key = 0x0f0f0f0f0f123456`, you get :

```
>>> hex(ror(key, 16))
'0x34560f0f0f0f0f12L'
>>> hex(ror(key, 16, 4))
'0x34560f12L'
```

exactly the same as C output

Answer (score 2):

i know its nearly 6 years old

I always find it easier to use string slices than bitwise operations.

```
def rotate_left(x, n):
    return int(f"{x:032b}"[n:] + f"{x:032b}"[:n], 2)

def rotate_right(x, n):
    return int(f"{x:032b}"[-n:] + f"{x:032b}"[:-n], 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotation_value(value, rotations, widht=32):
    """ Return a given number of bitwise left or right rotations of an interger 
    value,
    for a given bit field widht.
    if rotations == -rotations:
        left
    else:
        right
    """
    if int(rotations) != abs(int(rotations)):
        rotations = widht + int(rotations)
    return (int(value)<<(widht-(rotations%widht)) | (int(value)>>(rotations%widht))) & ((1<<widht)-1)
```