# Incorrect output from my implementation of SHA-256

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256, sha

For a personal project, I'm working on implementing SHA-256 in Python 3, without using the `hashlib` module (since that would defeat the purpose of learning how SHA-256 works). I've been working from the [Wikipedia pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode), but my code gives incorrect output (compared to the `hashlib` output). I've been staring at the code for an hour, and besides a headache, I've made no headway on figuring out what I've done wrong.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import hashlib
import sys

# ror function taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229191/2508324
def ror(val, r_bits, max_bits=32):
    return ((val & (2**max_bits-1)) >> r_bits%max_bits)|(val << (max_bits-(r_bits%max_bits)) & (2**max_bits-1))

h = [0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19]

k = [0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
   0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
   0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
   0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
   0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
   0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
   0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
   0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2]

s = sys.stdin.read().encode()
msg = [int(x,2) for c in s for x in '{:08b}'.format(c)]
msg.append(1)
while len(msg) % 512 != 448:
    msg.append(0)
msg.extend([int(x,2) for x in '{:064b}'.format(len(s))])

for i in range(len(msg)//512):
    chunk = msg[512*i:512*(i+1)] # sloth love chunk
    w = [0 for _ in range(64)]
    for j in range(16):
        w[j] = int(''.join(str(x) for x in chunk[32*j:32*(j+1)]),2)
    for j in range(16, 64):
        s0 = ror(w[j-15], 7) ^ ror(w[j-15], 18) ^ (w[j-15] >> 3)
        s1 = ror(w[j-2], 17) ^ ror(w[j-2], 19) ^ (w[j-2] >> 10)
        w[j] = (w[j-16] + s0 + w[j-7] + s1) % 2**32
    work = h[:]
    for j in range(64):
        S1 = ror(work[4], 6) ^ ror(work[4], 11) ^ ror(work[4], 25)
        ch = (work[4] & work[5]) ^ (~work[4] & work[6])
        temp1 = (work[7] + S1 + ch + k[j] + w[j]) % 2**32
        S0 = ror(work[0], 2) ^ ror(work[0], 13) ^ ror(work[0], 22)
        maj = (work[0] & work[1]) ^ (work[0] & work[2]) ^ (work[1] & work[2])
        temp2 = (S0 + maj) % 2**32
        work = [(temp1 + temp2) % 2**32] + work[:-1]
        work[4] = (work[4] + temp1) % 2**32
    h = [(H+W)%2**32 for H,W in zip(h,work)]

print(''.join('{:08x}'.format(H) for H in h))
print(hashlib.sha256(s).hexdigest())
```

If the implementation was correct, the two outputs would match. Instead, I get this (with input `abc`):

```
$ echo -n abc | ./sha256.py
203b1d9016060802fe5ef80436611159de1868b58d44940e3d3979eab5f4d193
ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
```

I have thoroughly examined the code, but I do not see any differences between it and the Wikipedia pseudocode. I suspect the error is in the compression loop (`for j in range(64):`). I've manually debugged and reviewed the state of the program up through initializing the first 16 words of the `w` array, and it all checks out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When does the code start to behave differently from what you expect?

Comment: @leovp Given that I'm trying to learn the workings of the algorithm, I don't have the knowledge necessary to pinpoint exactly where it is going wrong.

Comment: Try the cryptography stackexchange.

Comment: @Will I do not think this would be any better on Crypto.SE than here. It's not a question about the SHA-256 algorithm; it's a question about trying to implement it, which is more about programming than cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA1 works on bits, not bytes. Therefore, the 64 bit length at the end of the padding is expressed in bits as well; the mistake is in the line

```
msg.extend([int(x,2) for x in '{:064b}'.format(len(s))])
```

which should be

```
msg.extend([int(x,2) for x in '{:064b}'.format(len(s) * 8)])
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!