# Assembly x86 rotating a number right n times to obtain the same number

Tags: x86, nasm

Sometimes by rotating a number right we obtain the same number.

eg. 01010101 (85) can be rotated by 2,4,6 places to get the same number.what are the number of times we can rotate a number by different bits to get the same number?
For this I wrote the following code:

```
extern printf                   ; the C function to be called  
SECTION .data                   ; Data section  
msg:    db "The number of possible rotations  are : %d",10,0  
inta1:  dd  1234567   ; integer 1234567  

num: dd  1431655765  

SECTION .text                   ; Code section.  

global  main                ; "C" main program   
main:     
    mov eax, [num]    
    mov ecx,32  
    mov ebx,0  
    mov edx,eax  
.loop:  
    dec ecx  
    cmp ecx,1  
    jl .exit  
    ror eax,1  
    cmp edx,eax  
    jne .loop  
    inc ebx  
    jmp .loop  
.exit:  
        push ebx  
        push    dword msg 
        call    printf        
        add     esp, 8
```

Output for above code:
The number of possible rotations  are : 15
When num: 858993459
Output:
The number of possible rotations  are : 7
.

Although I get correct answers for 32 bit numbers, I am not able to use a non-32 bit in place of num in the same code to get the correct answer.
eg When I use num :85,
I get the output:
The number of possible rotations  are : 0
But it should have been 3
Maybe it is because of padding by zeros in the first remaining bits.(Not sure, Just assuming)
How do I use the same set of registers to display the value of possible rotations for a non-32 bit number too?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"non-32 bit number"_? Please add the non-working code.

Comment: @Michael For example a 8-bit number 01010101 (=85)  when right rotated by 2 places gives  01010101 which is again equal to 85. when right rotated by 4 places gives  01010101 which is again equal to 85.when right rotated by 6 places gives  01010101 which is again equal to 85. So the total number of possible rotations shoul be 3 but I get an output as 0. How to solve this?

Comment: EAX is a 32-bit register. If it contains 85 decimal and you rotate it right you would then have 10000000000000000000000000101010 in binary. If you want to handle 8-bit values use the AL register.

Comment: @JimRhodes That is my question. How do I get the answer=3  when using num as 85 by using the same set of extended registers?

Comment: @SaumyaSahay: Then do the rotation on `al` instead if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: @Michael I see that al is a 8 bit register. Using al I will not be able to use 32 bit numbers. I want to use 32 bit extended register and find the solution.

Comment: `al` is the least significant byte of `eax`. if you rotate `al` you'd only rotate those 8 bits.

Comment: @Michael Please bear with me if my questions are idiotic as I am really new to this. What if the number is user input, and we do not know, if it's a 8-bit, 16-bit or 32 bit number from before hand?

Comment: what I mean to ask is how should I alter the code so that no matter whatever random input number(obviously less than equal to 32 bit in size ) I use, I get the required answer.

Comment: By that logic, why would 85 (1010101) be an 8-bit number and not a 7-bit number?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I would appreciate to see some general answers with theoretical background :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your function / program needs two inputs: the number and the rotation width.

You can use the `rol` instruction for 8, 16, 32, and 64bit rotates.  You'll need different copies of the loop for each operand-size.

If you want to support arbitrary rotation widths, you'll have to emulate them with shifts and masking.  (Similar to [the pattern of shifts that C compilers recognize as a rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776523/224132).)

`rcl` will do 9, 17, 33, or 65bit rotates, but part of the number is in `CF` where you can't compare it easily.  I don't think rotate-through-carry will be helpful for this.

---

If you want to infer the rotation width from the number, you might use `bsr` to find the highest set bit.  You could optionally round that up to 8, 16, 32, or 64.

Make sure you test your program with input = `0`, because `bsr`'s register result is undefined for 0 inputs.  (Its flag result has ZF set).

---

#### RE: your actual code:

First of all, your function doesn't return, so you'll just crash, or get lucky and fall-through into a function that does return.  Add a `ret` instruction to the end.

Also, `dec` already sets flags.  You don't need a `cmp`.  You actually don't need a check there at all, since you're guaranteed to find a match after rotating back to the initial value.  It was possible to *dramatically* simplify your loop.  It should now run at one iteration per cycle on Intel CPUs.

I also put the format string and so on in read-only data, not private modifiable data.

```
extern printf

SECTION .rodata                 ; Read-only data section  

msg:  db  "The number of possible rotations  are : %d",10,0  
num:  dd  1431655765  

section .text
global  main
main:
    ;mov ebx,0  ; should be  xor ebx,ebx.  And you need to save/restore ebx if you're going to modify it.

    mov   eax, [num]
    mov   edx,eax
    xor   ecx,ecx

.rotcount:
    ror   eax, 1
    inc   ecx
    cmp   edx, eax  
    jne  .rotcount

    ;; ecx = number of 32bit rotates to produce a match.  Range: 1 to 32

    push    ecx  
    push    dword msg 
    call    printf        
    add     esp, 8

    xor   eax,eax     # return 0, instead of unpredictable behaviour from fall-through
    ret
```