# How do I refer to literal registers in gcc inline assembly in AT&T syntax?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am trying to refer to register literals; I need this because I want to use instructions like `mulx` which require one of their inputs to be in `rdx`.

I've tried this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint64_t x = 15, y = 3, z, w;
  asm ("mov %[x], rdx\t\n"
       "mulx %[y], %[z], %[w]\t\n"
       : [z] "=&r" (z), [w] "=&r" (w)
       : [x] "r" (x), [y] "r" (y)
       : "rdx"
       );
  return z + w;
}
```

which only works with `-masm=intel` and otherwise gives

```
$ gcc  foo.c
/tmp/ccGealWM.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `rdx'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and I've tried

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint64_t x = 15, y = 3, z, w;
  asm ("mov %[x], %rdx\t\n"
       "mulx %[y], %[z], %[w]\t\n"
       : [z] "=&r" (z), [w] "=&r" (w)
       : [x] "r" (x), [y] "r" (y)
       : "rdx"
       );
  return z + w;
}
```

which gives

```
$ gcc  foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:5:7: error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter
       asm ("mov %[x], %rdx\t\n"
       ^
```

Comment: You need to double the `%` that is `%%rdx`. It's a bad idea though, you should use a `"d"` constraint instead. Rule of thumb: if you write `mov` in inline asm, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Oooh, thanks!  `%%` works, if you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.  Why should I use a `"d"` constraint, though?  I'm seeing if I can match the performance of hand-written assembly by using my own script for register allocation and instruction scheduling (because gcc isn't good enough), and across the ~175 lines of assembly it generates, there's no single value that "lives" in `rdx`; things keep getting swapped into and out of `rdx` depending on which things need to be multiplied.  And I also need a `mov` to save `rbp` at the beginning, because I need 15 registers to not spill anything

Comment: In general you use inline assembly for inlining, and then it's better to inform the compiler so it can do clever stuff instead of forcing possibly unnecessary data movement. You might be doing something special where this doesn't apply, but then chances are you should use separate assembly module.

Comment: @JasonGross Given the `d` constraint, the compiler may choose registers for other instructions so that the result is in the right register ahead of time. (Also, if you don't constrain the registers, you'll get an error if the compiler happens to choose `rdx` anyway, because you can't `mov rdx, rdx`.)

Comment: @duskwuff you **can** `mov rdx, rdx` it's just a waste of resources :) Also, the clobber prohibits the compiler from picking `rdx`.

Comment: If the first or last instruction of an inline-asm statement is a `mov`, usually you're doing it wrong and should write better operand constraints.  See the [inline-assembly tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).  Or better, let the compiler use `mulx` for you by compiling that function with `-mbmi2`.  (e.g. with `__attribute__((target("-mbmi2") ))` or something if you need it in the same compilation unit as other functions.)