# x86 Assembly Programming (GAS Syntax): Operand type mismatch for `shl'

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, att

I am attempting to shift a number stored in the EAX register by the quantity stored in the EBX register. However, when I attempt to execute my program with the following shift statement:

```
shll %ebx, %eax
```

I retrieve the following error upon compilation:

> Error: operand type mismatch for `shl'

I am confused as to what this error means as from my understand, passing in register references as parameters should be the correct usage of a shift function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shift count in an x86 instruction must either be a constant or in the %cl register.  You can't use any other register for the shift count.  %ebx is neither a constant nor %cl, so you get an error.

[Intel's manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) shows the available forms of `shl`.

If you can assume support for BMI2 extensions, `shlx %ebx, %eax, %eax` allows the shift count to be an arbitrary register, and is faster on Intel CPUs. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx)

Comment: I think they tried using `ebx` as shift count (first operand in AT&T syntax). But other than that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is one of the top search engine hits for that message: the syntax required for an *immediate* shift count is: `shr $13, %ebx`

found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185989/493161