# Inline assembly size mismatch for 8-bit rotate

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly, att

I am trying to write the rotate left operation in C using inline assembly, like so:

```
byte rotate_left(byte a) {
    __asm__("rol %0, $1": "=a" (a) : "a" (a));
    return a;
}
```

(Where byte is typedefed as unsigned char).

This raises the error

> /tmp/ccKYcEHR.s:363: Error: operand size mismatch for `rol'.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Where do you define `byte`?

Comment: With AT&T syntax src and destination are reversed. Maybe you meant `"rol $1, %0"`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/z6Qof7 there's no need of inline assembly for this (at least for gcc and clang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT&T syntax uses the opposite order from Intel syntax.  The rotate count has to be first, not last:  `rol $1, %0`.

---

Also, you don't need and shouldn't use inline asm for this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

As described in [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c), GNU C has intrinsics for narrow rotates, because the rotate-idiom recognition code fails to optimize away an `and` of the rotate count.  x86 shifts/rotates mask the count with `count & 31` even for 8-bit and 16-bit, but rotates still wrap around.  It does matter for shifts though.

Anyway, gcc has a builtin function for narrow rotates to avoid any overhead.  There's a `__rolb` wrapper for it in `x86intrin.h`, but MSVC uses its own `__rotr8` and so on from its `intrin.h`.  Anyway, clang doesn't support either the `__builtin` or the `x86intrin.h` wrappers for rotates, but gcc and ICC do.

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t rotate_left_byte_by1(uint8_t a) {
    return __builtin_ia32_rolqi(a, 1);  // qi = quarter-integer
}
```

I used `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` like a normal person instead of defining a `byte` type.

This doesn't compile at all with clang, but [it compiles as you'd hope with gcc7.2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint8_t+rotate_left_byte_by1(uint8_t+a)+%7B%0A++++return+__builtin_ia32_rolqi(a,+1)%3B++//+qi+%3D+quarter-integer%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.30235729592831,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.36430937073837,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang401,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
rotate_left_byte_by1:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    rolb    %al
    ret
```

This gives you a function that compiles as efficiently as your inline asm ever could, but which can optimize away completely for compile-time constants, and the compiler knows how it works / what it does and can optimize accordingly.

Comment: As said above, gcc [does seem to recognize the naive rotate by one](https://godbolt.org/g/z6Qof7), so it doesn't even seem necessary to use any intrinsic; it's curious however that both VC++ and icc fail to recognize it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It recognizes it, but it's hard to get it to emit just `rolb` without an `and` to mask a runtime-variable count.  And perhaps the builtins were added before the idiom recognizer could handle byte and 16-bit rotates; I didn't check old gcc versions.

Comment: Update: VC++ [does recognize it](https://godbolt.org/g/fSn6YK) if I add liberally some casts to `uint8_t` (even just one on the left shift seems to work fine).

Comment: Uh yes, a runtime-known shift is more tricky; I was just testing the "rotate by fixed one" because that's what OP wrote in his question.

Comment: Still, 7.2 handles it just fine https://godbolt.org/g/9ZpN1d - no `and` in sight. From a quick binary search, it seems it started to handle it smartly from 4.9.0; 4.8.5 still generated horrible code for that.