# Proper way for declaring binary rotation preprocessor macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, binary, bit-manipulation

I would like to create macros for binary rotations. 
My goal was to make those macros universal for both `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` operand types.

I came to this implementation:

```
#define ROTL(X, N)  (((X) << (N)) | ((X) >> (8 * sizeof(X) - (N))))
#define ROTR(X, N)  (((X) >> (N)) | ((X) << (8 * sizeof(X) - (N))))
```

Those macros work fine but `gcc` compiler produces warnings during compilation:

```
warning: right shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
#define ROTL(X, N)  (((X) << (N)) | ((X) >> (8 * sizeof(X) - (N))))

warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
#define ROTL(X, N)  (((X) << (N)) | ((X) >> (8 * sizeof(X) - (N))))
```

I know that compiler is complaining about possible mismatch between type of `X` and `N`. But warnings are produced even when I cast both `X` and `N`:

```c
ROTL((uint32_t)0xdeadbeef, (uint32_t)0U);
```

What can I do to get rid of these warning the proper way?

Comment: This is not very efficient in terms of generated assembly code. If you need speed, you might want to use compiler intrinsics (heavily platform/compiler dependent).

Comment: You may have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c

Comment: Since these macros evaluate each argument twice, be careful that you don't call them with arguments that have side effects.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Actually, pretty much all compilers are nowadays smart enough to understand what's going on with the macro, and replace it with a proper intrinsic (see https://godbolt.org/z/R7WQgM). You would get this with gcc, clang, mcvc.

Comment: you need to show the actual macro calls to see why the compiler is giving you that warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get some problems when the second argument is zero or greater then the number of bits of the first argument. You may try to use the module to get rid of this problem. This seems to work, with this simple example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ROTL(X, N) \
    (((X) << ((N) % (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(X)))) | \
     ((X) >> ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(X) - (N)) % (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(X)))))

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        uint32_t a = ROTL(UINT32_C(0xdeadbeef), i);
        printf("%d\t%"PRIX32"\n", i, a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've used `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h` and `UINT32_C` and `PRIX32` from `inttypes.h`. You may adjust by yourself `ROTR` to do the same.

Comment: You might shift by negative amounts if N is negative.  Fixing that well is hard. Using a bit mask such as `& 0x1F` instead of modulus might work, but the mask has to be chosen correctly per type.

Comment: The mask should work, but is technically UB for signed types and negative values. Or treat a negative rotation as a rotate the other way. The compiler should optimise it all away when the rotate factor is a constant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Concerning [Fixing that well is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608994/proper-way-for-declaring-binary-rotation-preprocessor-macro/52611163#comment92154124_52609697).  I would recommend  to `CHAR_BIT` --> `(uintmax_t)CHAR_BIT` to insure an unsigned `%` operation.

Answer (score 2):

You get a warning only when the second argument is zero. So, just do nothing if `N == 0`:

```c
#define ROTL(X, N)  ((N) == 0 ? (X) : (((X) << (N)) | ((X) >> (8 * sizeof(X) - (N)))))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This version of macro answers to `What can I do to get rid of these warning the proper way?`, both for `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`

Comment: He gets a warning only when the second argument is zero. So handling it in a special way is, actually, a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Giovanni it doesn't handle this case: `ROTL(x, 32)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky The same warning will be for `(x << 32)` without _any_ macro

Comment: Well, actually the second argument must be in [0, (sizeof(X) * 8 - 1)], otherwise the algorithm does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

cast the shifted operand to the max possible width.

```
#define ROTL(X, N)  (((uint64_t)(X) << (N)) | ((uint64_t)(X) >> (8 * sizeof(X) - (N))))
```

Comment: This solution may works for `uint32_t` as input, but is not general, as produces the same warning when using `uint64_t` instead of `uint32_t`.