# asm error: "operand type mismatch for `rol'" with multiple input operands

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operands

**Environment: Debian 9.5 - gcc 6.3.0**

I can't get an embedded assembly function to work when I try to use multiple `InputOperands`.

I have the following code working (basic `rol` function, 1 `InputOperand`, predefined `rol` operand):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void asm_rol(int32_t* p_rolled)
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "rol %0, 1;"
        :"=a"(*p_rolled)
        :"a"(*p_rolled)
        :"cc"
    );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int32_t test = 0x1;
    asm_rol(&test);

    printf("0x%08x\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `0x00000002`, and is the correct result of `rol 0x1, 1`.

Now I don't understand why the following code does not compile. I think my usage of `InputOperands` is bad:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void asm_rol(int32_t* p_rolled, int16_t i)
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "rol %0, %1;"
        :"=a"(*p_rolled)
        :"a"(*p_rolled), "b"(i)
        :"cc"
    );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int32_t test = 0x1;
    asm_rol(&test, 1);

    printf("0x%08x\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc returns with the error:

```
resolve.c: Assembler messages:
resolve.c:6: Error: operand type mismatch for `rol'
```

I tried with `int8_t` and `int32_t` for `i`, it does not change anything.

I must say that I'm new to embedded asm in C in this environment, I've only done some basic inline assembly with Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Because the only register that is allowed for a shifting instruction that controls the number of bits to shift is _CL_ .

Comment: `void asm_rol(int32_t* p_rolled, int8_t i)
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "rol %0, %1;"
        :"+a"(*p_rolled)
        :"cI"(i)
        :"cc"
    );
}` may work

Comment: I think you mistyped it. I used `cI` (C-capital eye not C-elle). The `c` says to use the _CL_ register (assuming you change the type of variable `i` to int8_t instead of int16_t. . The Capital-Eye (`I`) says the constraint can also be an immediate value between 0 and 32. These machine constraints can be found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints  under the i386 info.

Comment: There's no reason to use inline asm for rotates.  [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508) shows that modern compilers can emit a `rol` or `ror` with no extra overhead, with no UB, for any input.  (And there are built-in functions for operand-sizes smaller than a dword where compilers sometimes have trouble.)

Comment: Indead it works, thanks. But why the following does not work ? I'd like to understand. `void asm_rol(int32_t* p_rolled, int8_t i) { __asm__ volatile ( ".intel_syntax noprefix;" "rol %0, %1;" :"=a"(*p_rolled) :"a"(*p_rolled), "cI"(i) :"cc" ); }` I know this syntax is too heavy, but I assume that later, "=a" and "a" could be different variables, so I'd like to understand how to handle this.

Comment: because `%1` is probably meant to be `%2` . The %2 means that it is mapped to the 3rd constraint. Constraint numbering is 0 based (0=1, 1=2, 2=3)

Comment: @NdFeB: Because the shift count is `%2` in that asm statement.  Use named constraints like `asm("rol %0, %[count]",  blah blah, [count] "cI" (i) );`  And use `"+r"` for the read-write input/output operand; there's no reason to force the compiler to use EAX/RAX.  Anyway, all of this is still worse than pure C, because it defeats constant propagation and other possible optimizations.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I know there are better solution for rotations. I am just learning to use embedded asm, that's all.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh my god, indeed. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you !!

Comment: When debugging inline asm, you should look at the compiler-generated asm to see what it substituted into the template.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/ is handy:  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  You can even do stuff like `nop # %0  %1  %2` to just see what the compiler picked for all the operands, whether you reference them in the template or not.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more guides and examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, explanations and references !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Petch said in the comments,

> the only register that is allowed for a shifting instruction that controls the number of bits to shift is CL

He also provided the following solution:

> ```
> void asm_rol(int32_t* p_rolled, int8_t i) {
>     __asm__ volatile
>     (
>         ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
>         "rol %0, %1;"
>         :"+a"(*p_rolled)
>         :"cI"(i) :"cc"
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> The c says to use the CL register (assuming you change the type of variable i to int8_t instead of int16_t. . The Capital-Eye (I) says the constraint can also be an immediate value between 0 and 32.

As Michael Petch and Peter Cordes pointed out in the comments, my code wasn't working because I was using `%1` as `rol` operand, but the correct variable was `%2`. I did this mistake because I thought only the `InputOperands` were referenced by `%#`.

Some nice documentation was also provided by Michael Petch and Peter Cordes:

> (...) machine constraints can be found here: [gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/…](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) under the i386 info
>
> There's no reason to use inline asm for rotates. [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c)
>
> When debugging inline asm, you should look at the compiler-generated asm to see what it substituted into the template. e.g. [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is handy: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output). You can even do stuff like nop # %0 %1 %2 to just see what the compiler picked for all the operands, whether you reference them in the template or not. See also [stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info) for more guides and examples.

Comment: I cannot upvote comments, and I cannot accept my own answer within 2 days. If someone wants to copy paste it, I would accept it with pleasure.

Comment: You made the effort to write up & format the comments, that's more than fine with me.  Go ahead and accept your own writeup in 2 days.

Comment: You don't need this asm statement to be `volatile`.  You *want* it to be optimized away if the new value of `*p_rolled` is never used.  Or to hoist it out of a loop if the same value is rotated by the same count multiple times.  Also, `"cc"` clobbers are implicit for inline asm on i386 and x86-64.  If you see examples without it, it's not wrong; adding it in is purely optional.

Comment: I probably would have written the function as taking an arg by value and returning a value, instead of `void`.  Shouldn't matter for performance once the function inlines, but easier to use: `int result = asm_rol(a, 4);` is nice.

Comment: Your `.intel_syntax noprefix` will break whatever compile-generated code follows it, unless the compiler was already emitting intel-syntax code from compiling with `-masm=intel`.  If you want it to work without `-masm=intel`, you'd need to restore AT&T syntax with `.att_syntax`.  But then it breaks if you *do* compile with `-masm=intel`.  You can use asm dialect alternatives, like `{%0, %1|%1, %0}` in this case, to make it work with both.  But normally people use AT&T syntax in GNU C inline asm.  At least that's what the Linux kernel does.  In your own projects you can do whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I cannot read AT&T, I just hate the syntax... I might learn it one day, but for now i stick to intel. I put `.intel_syntax` because i was getting errors with another code at compilation, but indeed specifying `-masm=intel` makes it useless.

Comment: I've read somewhere that inline extended asm was implicitly volatile, and I specified it to remember it. So this is wrong ?

Comment: @NdFeB If there are no output operands then volatile is implicit. Since all the changes are captured in both the input and output operands and there are no other side effects it can be removed. With optimizations on the extra volatile may force code to be generated when it isn't necessary.

Comment: If you want to get fancier, there's also `asm ("rol %[value], %[rollby]" : [value] "+a" (*p_rolled) : [rollby] "cI"(i) :"cc");`  Using symbolic names like that may not make much difference in a 1-liner asm like this.  But if things get more complicated, it's nice to not have to keep looking to see "which one is %2 again?"  And it's really nice if you end up needing to add or remove parameters.  Having to renumber everything is icky.  I might also change `"+a"`to just `"+r"`.  As Peter says, there's no need to force eax if the compiler has some other register that would work better.