# GCC extended inline assembly - "invalid instruction suffix for mov"

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I try to understand how the extended inline assembly in GCC works. But when I try to run a simple test program I get the error: "invalid instruction suffix for mov"

The sample program:

```
unsigned char destination;
unsigned char ret;
unsigned int somevalue;

asm ("movb %1, %%al\n\t"
    "push %1\n\t"
    "pop edx\n\t"
    "not %%al\n\t"
    "movb %%al, %0"
    : "=r" (destination), "=r"(somevalue)
    : "r" (ret));
```

`destination` shall be loaded into `al`. After that `somevalue` is pushed onto the stack. After that it is pop'd in the `edx` register. The `not` instruction shall be performed on `al` which contains the value of `destination`. After that the result shall be given out to `ret`. There is no restriction which registers to use to perform this program (I guess that means all registers as clobbers?).

Comment: Look at the compiler-generated asm output (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/) to see how GCC fills in the asm template.  `%1` will be a 32-bit register (because `unsigned int`).  So `movb %ecx, %al` obviously can't work because the operands are different sizes.  Perhaps you want `%b1` to print the byte version of that reg name?  You're reading an `"=r"` output-only operand so IDK what you want this to do.  **And it's impossible to make this usable because you leave the asm with ESP/RSP modified by `push` - there's no way to tell GCC about this.**  Also you forgot to declare an EAX clobber

Comment: Are you sure you're using GCC and not clang (e.g. on MacOS which installs clang as `gcc`)?  If you're using an option for Intel-syntax assembly then clang's assembler won't accept `movb` only `mov`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I'm using GCC. The standard compiler you get when you install Code::Blocks (the IDE I use). I'm using it on a Windows 8.1 VM.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have to admit that I do not really understand the inline assembly yet. The push instruction was just put in because I need to know how the inline assembly works, when I have 2 input variables. The program is just a slightly altered copy of the sample program from the [documentary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). That's where the "=r" comes from.

Comment: @PeterCordes The most helpful thing would be if you could give me a functional sample program in inline assembly that would do what I wrote as a description under the code chunk. So I understand what exactly is wrong with my code. (I altered the code chunk and the description).

Comment: It's meaningless to read from an output-only operand, and `%1` is `someval` not `destination`.  You should generally avoid push/pop in inline asm.  What plain C function are you trying to implement with asm?  Are you trying to do `destination = ret = ~someval;`?

Comment: It is (generally) a mistake to specify which registers to use: eg the `%%al` and `edx` (I assume you meant `%%edx`) you use.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237447) to another question.  If you do need specific registers for particular instructions, it is better to use the right "operand constraint" -- for `EAX` as an output you would specify `=a (foo)`.  Otherwise, if you must use (say) `EBX`, you **must** tell the compiler by specifying a "clobber".   By the way, you can write one instruction per `__asm__()` statement, which may make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: As @PeterCordes says, the problem with the `movb %1, %%al` is that `%1` refers to `"=r"(somevalue)`: (leaving to one side the fact that the `=` means that this is an _output_) the `r` says this is a register and the `%1` will expand to whatever 32-bit register gcc has allocated for `somevalue` to be read into -- the result is (say) `movb %%ecx, %%al`, which ain't valid.  The one of the "x86 Operand Modifiers" will do the trick, thus `movb %b1, %%al` will ask for the (ls) byte of the register allocated for `somevalue`.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code again. I used `=a`, `=b` etc. to work with the registers. My program now seems to work: `asm("push %%ebx\n\t"
    "pop %%edx\n\t"
    "not %%al\n\t"
    : "=a" (ret)
    : "a" (destination), "b"(somevalue)
    );`