# Rotating byte N places

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm working on rotating the bytes of integer numbers.
The first thing I'm attempting to do is grabbing the lower N amount of bits and higher n amount of bits. Because after I call my shift(n) it will cut those bits off either at the higher and or lower end depending if it's rotating left or right.
So far I have my low working and it's grabbing the correct bits. My high is not grabbing the correct bits I'm trying to use k and m to grab my high bits.
After I call my shift I need to add the bits that were cut off back onto the opposite side of where I grabbed it from.
I'm struggling with getting the logic of how I would add back those cut of bits and how to grab the high n amount of bits. And tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

`NBITS` -> the amount of bits in the byte
`Shift(n)` -> shifts n amount of bits to either left or right depending if n is positive or negative

```
void shift(int n)         // If n > 0, shifts bits right n places; if n < 0,left
{   
    if (n > 0)
        bits = bits >> n;
    else if (n < 0)
        bits = bits << -n;
}

void rotate(int n)
{   
    int k = NBITS - 1; // last position
    int m = (NBITS - 1) - n + 1; // to desired position
    int low = bits & ((1 << n) - 1);
    int high = (bits & (((1 << (m - k + 1)) - 1) << k)) >> k;
   
    assert(abs(n) <= NBITS);
    if (n > 0) { // rotate right n places 
        shift(n);
        //put back cut off bits
    }
    else if (n < 0) { // rotates left
        shift(n);
        //put back cut off bits
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `shift`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) if you haven't already; there are some good approaches there.

Comment: @SuperStormer I edited my code to show the shift function. All it does is shift the byte over n amount of bits if n is positive it shifts it right. If n is negative it shifts it left.

Comment: I suggest you look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-bits-of-an-integer/ too

Comment: Here you can run and try that code https://onlinegdb.com/SJVaUa-7u