# How to write inline assembly to bit rotate

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I was reading [gcc's guide on extended ASM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and I'm running into a problem where the compiler isn't interpreting the assembly the way I thought it would. I thought I'd try it with a bit rotate instruction since those aren't readily available in C.

Here's my C function:

```
int rotate_right(int num,int count) {
    asm (
        "rcr %[value],%[count]"
        : [value] "=r" (num)
        : [count] "r" (count)
        );

    return num;
}
```

And the compiled output using x86-64 gcc (trunk) -O0:

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        rcr eax,eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

The problem I'm having is that GCC is taking my inline assembly to mean "rotate `EAX` by `EAX` rather than by the `count` parameter I intended. This is what I *expected to get:*

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        rcr     eax,ecx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Note that while the language might not natively support rotate your compiler very likely offers it as an intrinsic.  With gcc check if your installation has a "ia32intrin.h" and the __rolb, __rolw, __rold, __rolq and __rorb, __rorw, __rord, __rorq functions. MSVC offers similar functionality, just using different headers and function names.

Comment: Did you actually want 33-bit rotate-with-carry instead of a normal 32-bit rotate?  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror.  You haven't specified anything that would produce a carry input even in your "expected" version.  But plain ROL / ROR are a solved problem without inline asm: [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508)

Comment: @PeterCordes I wanted the normal 32-bit one. I'm so used to the Z80 mnemonics ```RRA``` for 9-bit rotate-with-carry and ```RRCA``` for 8-bit rotate that when I go to most other CPUs I can't remember which one is which.

Comment: Are you sure that's right?  A recent retrocomputing Q&A about 8080's backward mnemonic convention ([Why are the Intel 8080's rotate instructions called opposite to intuition?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24786)) has an answer saying RRA was a normal 8-bit rotate-right, while the mnemonic including a C (RRCA) was the one rotating through carry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `+r` constraint for `num` indicating that `num` will be read and not just written to.  Otherwise gcc will assume that the previous value of `num` doesn't matter and just picks an unused register to dump the output into.

You'll also have to use a `c` constraint for `count` as the shift amount must be in `cl` for the `ror` instruction.  Refer to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833319/417501) for a more detailed explanation.

Before doing any inline assembly programming, read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) carefully!  It is somewhat tricky to get right and there are many subtle details to pay attention to.

Also note that even if the inline assembly seems to work right, it is possible to be incorrect, e.g. due to missing clobbers that just so happen to not affect anything relevant with this particular compiler version at this particular optimisation level for this particular version of the code.  So be extra careful and try to avoid using it if possible.

For example in your case, you can just use the standard C rotation idiom.  The compiler will pick it up as long as optimisations are enabled:

```
#include <limits.h>

int rotate_right(int num,int count) {
    return ((unsigned)num >> count | num << CHAR_BIT * sizeof num - count);
}
```

Comment: I really find gcc's inline asm syntax much worse than Visual Studio's. It's almost as if GCC is trying to discourage users from using assembly... ;)

Comment: Why cast `num` in one place and not all places?

Comment: Worth noting that unless count in the `[1... CHAR_BIT * sizeof num)` range, code is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because it doesn't make a difference in the other case.  As for the undefined behaviour, that's technically true but well known not to be a problem in practice in this particular case.

Comment: @puppydrum64 The main difference is that MSVC-style inline assembly was designed for convenience and for being able to write long code sequences with it.  Back in the day, users would possibly not have an assembler in their toolchain, so inline assembly had to be heavily used whenever you needed any sort of assembly.  Gcc's style on the other hand is designed to patch in individual instructions the compiler doesn't know about and requires you to specify all side effects the instruction has so the optimiser can do its job.  It's meant for performance, nothing else.

Comment: Hmmm, In the case where `count==CHAR_BIT * sizeof num-1`, "it doesn't make a difference in the other case." --> `num << 31` unnecessarily incurrs UB when `(unsigned) num << 31` does not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Undefined behaviour remains with `count == 32`, so no need to account for the `count == 31` case separately unless you also fix the other one.

Comment: @puppydrum64 and fuz: for C that compiles efficiently to `ror` / `rol` with well-defined behaviour for every count, see [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508).  This is a solved problem without using inline asm, although it is somewhat tricky to avoid UB and still write something that compilers can recognize as not needing any extra instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. I can't help but wonder though, why ```ror``` and ```rol``` haven't made it to a standard library yet.

Comment: @puppydrum64: C++20's `<bit>` header has `std::rotr` and `std::rotl`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl.  It allows negative rotate counts, but apparently that Just Works on 2's complement machines.  https://godbolt.org/z/7z51dxccv shows GCC compiling it to a single `ror` instruction.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me solve your problem as stated in the title.

```
static inline int ror(int num, int count) {
  __asm__ ("ror\t%0, %b1" : "+r"(num) : "c"(count));
  return num;
}

ror(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     ecx, esi
        ror     eax, cl
        ret
```

This is how you do it, and don't forget `-masm=intel`. I'll explain some details below, but basically, you have to read carefully the GCC docs.

---

Quoting the OP,

> I really find gcc's inline asm syntax much worse than Visual Studio's. It's almost as if GCC is trying to discourage users from using assembly...

It's worse in a sense that it takes more time to learn, but after you know the details, it's a powerful tool for various low level programing and optimization.

One case I use inline assembly in an actual program is to use the `rcpss` instruction. There is an Intel intrinsic for it, but the current version of GCC (12.1) produces quite horrible code when you use it for a single `float`.

```
static inline float float_recip(float x) {
  if (__builtin_constant_p(x)) {
    return 1 / x;
  }
  __asm__ ("rcpss\t%0, %0" : "+x"(x));
  return x;
}
```

This is the actual code. `__builtin_constant_p` makes constant substitution possible when the value of `x` is known at compile-time. I intentionally put both operands the same to avoid the false dependency problem.

See how the assembly is generated when it's called somewhere.

```
float f(float x) {
  return float_recip(x) + float_recip(2);
}

f(float):
        rcpss   xmm0, xmm0
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1056964608
```

You can see `float_recip(2)` is replaced with a `0.5f` constant, and all the unnecessary copies are gone.

You cannot do this with MSVC inline assembly, apart from that it's not even supported for 64-bit.

Comment: You probably want `"ci"(count)` to allow the count to be an immediate (if inlining and constant folding make that possible.)  Normally you'd care about immediate range limits, but truncating the count to an imm8 is exactly equivalent; the instruction itself is going to keep only the low 5 or 6 bits of the count anyway.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror)

Answer (score 0):

No difference with GCC that writing it in C.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t rotl64 ( uint64_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (64 - r));
}

uint64_t rotl64_assembly(uint64_t num, int8_t count) {
  __asm__ ("rol\t%0, %b1" : "+r"(num) : "c"(count));
  return num;
}
```

Result:

```
rotl64(unsigned long, signed char):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     ecx, esi
        rol     rax, cl
        ret

rotl64_assembly(unsigned long, signed char):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     ecx, esi
        rol     rax, cl
        ret
```

You can play with it here: https://godbolt.org/z/3xfs5EhWv

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization; the asm is a mess!  Also, your `rotl64` in C implies a value-range of 1..63 for `r`, otherwise the C abstract machine would have shift-count UB.  If you don't want compilers to assume that `if (r >= 64)` is always false in code that uses `r` as a rotate count, see [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508) for how to write shifts that can compile to a single rotate without UB for any rotate count, including 0.  (I'm not sure if real compilers would make that optimization, but they're allowed to assume th

Comment: @PeterCordes  yup. sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: @PeterCordes and anyway as you see they translate to the same code.

Comment: Yes, they compile to the same asm, but your pure-C version has undefined behaviour for r=0 or r=64, or larger values.  Inlining into other callers, it might *not* compile to the same asm for other code because the shifts imply a value-range for `r`. (In theory the rotate itself could compile to something else, but in practice that's unlikely.) Also, compiling with `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` would raise an error in that case, while the inline asm would silently get the x86 semantics of truncating the count. You can get well-defined behaviour while still compiling to a single `rol`, see the link

Comment: I saw the link, but I don't get it... can you correct the code?

Comment: `mask = (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n) - 1);` and `return (x<<(r&mask)) | (x>>( (-r)&mask ));`.  Literally just change the type for the first arg in the `rotl32` in [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776523) - the `sizeof` in the mask calculation will adapt it.

Comment: so it should be r=r&63 but it produced the same code: https://godbolt.org/z/KM4KaYxTb

Comment: Of course it compiles to the same code when not inlined into anything, that's what we want, to avoid UB for all `r` without costing any performance.  In a function that calls this, compilers could legally optimize `r == 0` to a constant `false`, because they're allowed to assume that shift-count UB doesn't happen.  https://godbolt.org/z/nMq6af3j4 shows current GCC/clang don't actually do that. But compiling with `-fsanitize=undefined` shows my version is "clean", no checks for anything, your version still isn't because you only mask once so `64-r` can still be 64` for `r=0`.

Comment: Also, your answer forgot to mention that it only works if you compile with `-masm=intel`.  (Which is not recommended for production use, e.g. it makes GCC unable to compile a program that uses a global `int offset;` variable, also any variable with the same name as a register.  [A variable named "offset" causes "Error: invalid use of register" to appear when using "-masm=intel" in gcc, but no error in AT&T mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77162713))