# A variable named "offset" causes "Error: invalid use of register" to appear when using "-masm=intel" in gcc, but no error in AT&T mode

Tags: c, gcc, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I tried to compile a very simple program using gcc with `-masm=intel` option.  But instead "Error: invalid use of register" appears.

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
size_t offset;

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
        offset = 20;
        return 0;
}
```

result:

```text
$ gcc test.c -masm=intel
/tmp/ccPnqEmz.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccPnqEmz.s:19: Error: invalid use of register
```

But when I delete the assignment statement, it can compile normally:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
size_t offset;

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
        //offset = 20;
        return 0;
}
```

result:

```text
$ gcc test.c -masm=intel
$
```

When I looked at the assembly code of both, I only found that the former had one more store instruction than the latter, implementing the `offset = 20` assignment:

```asm
        mov     QWORD PTR offset[rip], 20
```

Why does the GNU assembler choke on this instruction GCC emitted?

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug in gcc.

Comment: This has, in fact, already been reported as <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929>, <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87986>, <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95652> and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `offset` is a keyword in Intel-syntax assembly.

The GNU assembler in Intel-syntax mode follows the Microsoft assembler convention that mentioning a bare symbol name in an assembly instruction produces a memory operand with that symbol’s address, and not an immediate operand.  To choose an immediate-operand interpretation, one needs to put the `offset` keyword before the symbol.

```asm
        mov     esi, var         # loads the value from memory at var
        mov     esi, offset var  # loads the address of var
```

NASM has the opposite convention, where one would instead write:

```asm
        mov     esi, [var]       ; loads the value from memory at var
        mov     esi, var         ; loads the address of var
```

In GNU assembler’s AT&T syntax, these would be:

```asm
        movl    var, %esi        # loads the value from memory at var
        movl    $var, %esi       # loads the address of var
```

When the GNU assembler parses the code produced by the compiler, the word `offset` is interpreted as a keyword and not as a symbol name, which confuses the assembler’s parser.  To disambiguate the meaning when writing assembly code by hand, you can put the symbol name in quotes:

```asm
        mov     QWORD PTR "offset"[rip], 20
```

This will be correctly parsed and interpreted by the assembler.  (NASM uses `$` for that purpose.)

The same problem would appear if you named a variable identically to a register, with the same fix.  Intel syntax is rarely used with the GNU assembler, especially when GCC is normally used to compile code, which means it was very easy for this bug to slip through.

Comment: GCC definitely treats `-masm=intel` as a second-class citizen; it mostly exists for the benefit of humans that want to look at the asm.  GCC *could* use quotes on symbol names (always or when they match a register or keyword) but chooses not to, because they don't think it's important, I guess.  It would either slow compilation a bit and take extra code for GCC devs to maintain (checking a table every time a symbol is output in asm) or make the output noisier for humans, partially defeating the purpose.

Comment: `.intel_syntax noprefix` also has an ambiguity with `.equ` constants defined before vs. after their use which AT&T syntax doesn't have: [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel\_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39355188)  (GAS is a one-pass-over-the-source assembler, making decisions other than branch displacement in the first pass.)