# Segmentation fault at the `pop rbp` instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, stack, x86-64

The following assembly code causes a segmentation fault exiting from the main function at the `pop rbp` instruction. This code was generated by a compiler I'm writing, so don't mind the superfluous instructions:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global main

.text
add:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 4
    mov dword [rbp - 4], edi
    sub rsp, 4
    mov dword [rbp - 8], esi

    mov eax, dword [rbp - 4]
    mov ebx, dword [rbp - 8]
    add eax, ebx
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov eax, 60
    mov edi, eax
    mov eax, 9
    mov esi, eax
    call add
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
    add rsp, 4
```

I've double checked I'm keeping the stack in order, so I don't see how this error could be occurring.

I've tried debugging it with GDB, but with not much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `dword ptr`.

Just plain `dword` is defined as `4` like in MASM, so `mov dword [rbp - 4], edi` is actually
`mov 4[rbp - 4], edi` = `mov [rbp + 0], edi`, overwriting the saved RBP.  (So your `add` function corrupts the caller's RBP).

In GDB with a "disassembly" view while single-stepping (`layout asm`), this was immediately obvious; I was already suspicious of that code because of those inefficient `sub rsp, 4` / `mov` pairs - you should just change RSP once on function entry with `sub rsp, 8` to reserve all the stack space you're going to need, ahead of both stores.

(Or perhaps use `push rdi` / `mov [rbp-4], esi`, but if you ever plan to do register allocation for variables instead of always spilling them on function entry, most functions won't need that optimization; [mainstream C compilers don't look for it even in debug builds where they do always spill everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395/what-c-c-compiler-can-use-push-pop-instructions-for-creating-local-variables).)

For debugging stuff like this, `watch -l *(long*)$rbp` inside `add` (after `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp`) also works: continue from there shows the `mov  DWORD PTR [rbp+0x0],edi` changing that memory location.

The other clue is that RSP = `0x7fff0000003c` when `pop rbp` faults, which should make you suspect that the low half has been overwritten with a small integer.  (And since we just ran `mov rsp, rbp`, and the RBP value is similarly corrupted, that's the obvious thing to suspect.)

---

---

Also, you wouldn't have this problem with AT&T syntax, or with NASM where keywords like `dword` aren't land-mines that will silently break your code if you use them wrong.

GAS `.intel_syntax` is not as robust.  For example GCC itself will make broken asm if you have a global variable called `long rax;` or `int offset;`.  *[A variable named "offset" causes "Error: invalid use of register" to appear when using "-masm=intel" in gcc, but no error in AT&T mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162713/a-variable-named-offset-causes-error-invalid-use-of-register-to-appear-when)*.

It's possible to `call "rax"` with the quotes escaping it from being treated as a register name, but GCC doesn't do that; `-masm=intel` is a second-class citizen for GCC, intended mostly for humans to read the asm, apparently not for production use.  (*[Disambiguate labels from register names in the Intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605964/disambiguate-labels-from-register-names-in-the-intel-syntax)*)  In NASM, you'd need `call $rax` to force treating it as a symbol.

GAS `.intel_syntax` also has an ambiguity depending on `.equ` appearing before or after code that uses it. *[Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355188/distinguishing-memory-from-constant-in-gnu-as-intel-syntax)*

I always prefer Intel syntax for disassembly, but most projects with hand-written asm don't use it for their source code.  For automated code-gen, AT&T is probably a better bet, unless you want to support inline asm using Intel syntax.  Then just be aware of the limitations.

Comment: (I know this has come up before, at least for MASM itself, but I couldn't find a duplicate.  Unsurprisingly, searching for `gnu assembler "dword" "4" "dword ptr"` wasn't useful, not restricting to hits where `dword` appeared without `ptr`.)