# _rotl64 not producing any code in windows program using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: rotation, visual-studio-2022

Trying to rotate a 64 bit number by 4 bits but compiler not generating any code, warnings or errors.

```
        _rotl(X[h], 4);
```

_rotl,_rotl64, _rotr, _rotr64 - All produce no code.

_lrotl produced the following assembly code:

```
movsxd  rax, DWORD PTR h$13[rbp]
mov edx, 4
mov ecx, DWORD PTR X$[rbp+rax*4]
call    _lrotl
```

Have tried the console app example from the learn.microsoft.com page

_rotl64(val, 3) produces

```
mov edx, 3
mov rcx, QWORD PTR val2$[rbp]
call    _rotl64
```

As expected.

Comment: I would probably remove the rotation tag since it's not meant to be used this way, and add the appropriate assembly tag(s)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer halfway down

[Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c)

so added '#include <immintrin.h>' at the top of the affected file, compiler now produces the expected results:

; 390  :            int o = _rotl64(X[h], 4) & 0x0f;

```
movsxd  rax, DWORD PTR h$13[rbp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR X$[rbp+rax*4]
rol rax, 4
and rax, 15
mov DWORD PTR o$15[rbp], eax
```