# How to make an adder function with these characters?

Tags: c, function, math

I saw a "puzzle", where you have to write a function in C that returns the value of `a+c`, however, you can't use the `+` operator.

```
unsigned f(unsigned a, unsigned c) {
    return <write your coe here>;
}
```

You can use only the following characters: `harc()&|[]*/`.

Comment: Looks like they want you to invoke undefined behavior by casting an input to a `char *` and using subscripting for pointer arithmetic. **This is not guaranteed to work.**

Comment: @EdHeal: Is that a good hint? I don't see how that would work.

Comment: Is it necessary to use all characters in `harc()&|[]*/` or lesser can be used?

Comment: @haccks You don't have to use all of them.

Comment: @klenium; Good. Are you sure last character in the list is `/` and not `\\` ?

Comment: @haccks - doesn't matter - you don't need it. There's one other you don't need either.

Comment: @haccks: Irrelevant. Hint: `/* */`

Comment: This is close to what you seem to be looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/366247/1187415.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work in practice, though I believe it relies on undefined behaviour and will generate warnings:

```
unsigned f(unsigned a, unsigned c) {
    return &(((char*)a)[c]);
}
```

(fewer brackets are necessary in practice)

This works as follows:

```
   (char*)a      - cast 'a' to a 'char *' pointer 
  ((char*)a)[c]  - treat 'a' as an array, and index the c'th element, which
                   will be at address c + a
&(((char*)a)[c]) - take the address of that element, i.e. c + a
```

Finally the `return` casts this back to `unsigned`.

Trivial test harness which compiles with gcc 4.8 with two warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned
f (unsigned a, unsigned c)
{
  return &(((char *) a)[c]);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned a = 1;
  unsigned b = 2;
  unsigned c = f (a, b);
  printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Note as this is C, not C++, it may not compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Awesome! And can you explain why it works/what's happening?

Comment: `error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'unsigned int'` is what I get

Comment: @simplicisveritatis - g++ 4.7.something vomits this error message, while gcc 4.7.sameSomething turns it into working code.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Compiles file here with gcc 4.8 (albeit with two warnings) and works. Compiling with g++ won't work as g++ compiles C++ and this is C.

Comment: Just cured it using `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>`  if you want add it to your answer. Ugly, but it works ! :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis no, that would not be OK as most of the characters in `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>` are not permitted. This is a C challenge, not a C++ challenge, and `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>` is not valid C. C and C++ are different (albeit related) languages.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis, no, that would not be OK either as none of the characters `i`, `n` or `t` are permitted.

Comment: actually, the posted answer compiles with 4 warnings, 1) unused parameter `argc` 2) unused parameter `argv` 3) line 6 cast to pointer to integer of different size 4) return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: suggest changing the signature of the main() function to: `int main( void )`