# Addition without using a + sign

Tags: c++, c

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return (int)&(((char *)a)[b]);
}
```

Why am I supposed to cast `a` to a `char *` and not `int *`?

I'm trying to understand this code fully but I can't, so if it's easy to you, please, provide a simple English explanation.

Comment: This code does not compile on GCC and Clang.

Comment: where did you get this code?

Comment: The best thing about this code that you can do - throw it in garbage and never mention it again.

Comment: Why isn't a + b possible? But this is ABSOLUTELY bad. Why? Please... why??

Comment: Do you really want to use this code.. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365522/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-the-operator

Comment: `s[i]` is equivalent to `*(s + i)`, the code abuse of that.

Comment: This code does not make any sense, it's not even legal. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Why minuses? the addition wors just fine. You minus this post because you rage or something?

Comment: @Tracy because the code is terrible.

Comment: One could argue that the code is using `+` here: `((char *)a)[b]`, given that  `a[b]` is a shorthand for `*(a + b)`

Comment: `int add(int a, int b) { return a - - b; }` No plus sign.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: by converting to int an (invalid) address computed by adding `a` and `b` via pointer arithmetic.

Comment: why addition? when a[b] == example, 100[103]. Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I supposed to cast a to a char * and not int *?

To clarify for the readers of the question, you aren't *supposed* to use code like this at all. But let us assume that you're competing in the [ioccc](http://ioccc.org/years.html) (is there a C++ variant of this competition?), in which case this may be exactly what you're supposed to do.

So, to answer the question, it is because pointer arithmetic is scaled by the size of the pointed object. If you used `int*`, then `b` would be scaled by `sizeof(int)`. Since you don't want to scale either operand of an addition, you scale with 1 (the multiplicative identity) which happens when the pointed type has the size 1 - which by definition `char` has.

P.S. The program is ill-formed and may fail to compile on standard compliant compilers.

Comment: There is no ioc++cc.  There would be no challenge in writing unreadable C++.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't ask this question from my main acc because i knew the reaction would be. But you are right, this is for a competition.

Comment: @Tracy I think that stating that the intention is to write obfuscated code, and that this is not for production use might have softened the reaction. Not all readers of this site will understand implicitly. Some of them (and people who don't want such people to become confused) may wish that this would be voted into the oblivion.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that an array is simply an addition of a pointer with an index. If `a` is a `char []` (or `char *`) and `b` is an integer, then `a[b]` is the value at the address `a+b`. This code is casting `a` as a pointer, indexing it with b, and finding the address, which should equal `a+b`.

But in the real world, don't ever ever ever do this.

Comment: ...and the code uses a hidden `+`, namely that `a[b]` means `*(a+b)`.

Comment: So? The original question was "without using a + sign". The code doesn't use a + sign.

Comment: @GraemePerrow why it gets added? I mean, a[b], example, 100[103] == 100+103.

Comment: That's just how array access is defined in C. If `a` is a pointer to type X and `b` is an integer, then `a[b]` refers to the value in memory address `a + b*sizeof(X)`. And `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so this ends up being `a+b`.

Comment: @GraemePerrow got it. Thanks.

Comment: @GraemePerrow btw, you mentioned this works in C, but how about c++?

Comment: I recompiled it as a C++ program and with no changes, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To make it compile you need to turn it into valid c++. Pointers are incompatible with integers, but the distance between two pointers is an integer type:

```
#include <iterator>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    auto p = (char *)0;
    auto p2 = &(&p[a])[b];

    return static_cast<int>(std::distance(p, p2));
}
```

Disclaimer: I do not endorse this product or service.

Comment: FYI the code in the original question compiles (as C) and works with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: In the calculation of `p2`, you have the expression `p[a]`.  That is undefined behaviour because `p` is a null pointer.

Comment: @MartinBonner the expression is `&p[a]` - After the c-style cast, p is not a null pointer, it is simply a pointer to char. Whether taking the address of p[a] is UB or not I'm afraid I don't know the standard deeply enough to comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner I do believe that it's not UB. I've investigated this some time ago, but don't remember the standard quote. The expression being an argument to the addressof operator is crucial - it is not evaluated.

Comment: @RichardHodges: `p` is not a *null pointer constant*, but it *is* a pointer (specifically, pointer to char) which is null.  If you write `*p`, that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303: Oooh!  You may be right.  I can't remember whether it is C or C++ where that is true though.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example with a as 100 and b as 103

1. `(char *)a`  --> this typecasts a as a pointer. So a will be considered as a pointer.
2. `((char *)a)[b]`  --> this is 100[103], i.e. it gives the value at the location (100 + 103)
3. `&(((char *)a)[b]`  --> this gives the address of the above value, i.e. it gives 203.
4. `(int)&(((char *)a)[b]`  --> the final typecast to int will convert the 
   address above to an integer value as required by the return value of the function.

This will only work with `char*` typecast in step 2. If you use an `int*` typecast there, the sum that you get at step 3 will be `100 + 4*103` i.e. `512`

Comment: "this is 100[103]" should be "this is undefined behavior".

Comment: `a` is a character pointer at that stage. so `a[b]` is well defined.

Comment: Rishikesh, please be a bit more precise. In point 2, the value is never taken (would segfault); in point 4 there is no "char value", just an address.

Comment: 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting "The definition of the subscript operator []
is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`." So the addition operator is used implicitly, and then this applies, 6.5.6: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."  So you answer isn't correct, because it pretends that the code has predictable behavior.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje why it's added?i mean, 100[103] why 100+103??

Comment: @Tracy It is added because that is how the address of an array works. `a[b]` is equal to `*(a+b)`. As per pointer addition, when you add 1, the address increased by the size of the type. In this case, it is a character. So the address increases by `103`