# Assembly [ASM]: Adding without using arithmetic operators

Tags: assembly, x86, addition

How can I add two registers together without `add`, `adc`, `sub`, `sbb`, `inc`, and `dec`?

Comment: You forgot to mention what architecture. For x86, you can use `LEA`.

Comment: @Jester For x86

Comment: @Jester How about `movd mm0,eax; movd mm0,ecx; paddd mm0,mm1; movd eax,mm0`?

Comment: x86 is (sort of) Turing-complete using just MOV instructions, doing math with memory addressing modes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799928/224132.  (Of course LEA can do addition directly using address-mode syntax and machine encoding, but not subtraction.  Although you didn't mention `neg`, so `neg` + `lea` can subtract.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I just took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365544/3298930) and translated it to assembly, the numbers to sum are in `ax` and `bx`, while registers `cx` and `dx` are used to get intermediate results, the final result is in `dx` :

```
  mov ax, 12801  ;◄■■ FIRST NUMBER.
  mov bx, 2017   ;◄■■ SECOND NUMBER.

l1:

  mov cx, ax
  and cx, bx

  mov dx, ax
  xor dx, bx

  mov ax, cx
  shl ax, 1

  mov bx, dx

  cmp ax, 0   ;◄■■ IF AX != 0 REPEAT.
  jne l1

;RESULT IN DX = 14818
```

Comment: Nicely complicated. How about `mov si, ax; lea dx, [bx+si]` (if we stick to 16 bit which nobody said to).

Comment: I have this burning desire to optimize the code you present here, except that would be completely absurd because if you actually wanted optimal code, you'd use `add`!