# How do I write an addition function in MIPS without using the add* instruction(s)?

Tags: function, mips, addition

I've been given a project to write a program that does all arithmetic. thing is we can't use any of the predetermined functions such as mult, add, addi etc. the multiplication one I can do but how do I do addition or even subtraction without the use of those instructions?

Comment: If you can't use those instructions, what can you use?

Comment: [What is the best way to add two numbers without using the + operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/365522/995714)