# How would '1+1' look when just using 1 and 0?

Tags: binary, low-level

Is that possible? Can this be done using just 1 and 0 (true/false, on/off ...)?

If so, how would this code look?

If this example is too complex i am open to all other kinds of examples, but would like to have an operation included, because i have no idea how such operations get encoded (i guess they also are just an entry in a conversion chart)

The reason why i ask this, is that i want to give people a concrete example why datatypes and functions/operations are a practical abstraction (easier to read). Im writing a tutorial.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific programming language like C or ASM? Or how the plus operation is physically implemented on the cpu? This is extremely vague.

Comment: Physically implemented. How does it look when just using 1 and 0.

Comment: Almost all CPUs use "only 1 and 0". And there's a ton of info out there on how this type of thing works. (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)

Comment: Have a look also at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)

Comment: @bitmask what is the definition of `S` and `C` in the sentence `The half adder adds two single binary digits A and B. It has two outputs, sum (S) and carry (C) ` in the wikipedia lemma given by you?

Comment: It says so in the sentence? S is the sum, C the carry. If you add two one-bit values, you cannot necessarily express the result in one bit. Read the article, it literally explains what a carry is in the **next sentence**. If you are writing a tutorial for other people you should know this, and if you don't you should not tutor other people (before you understand what you teach).

Comment: Oh well, i have read `sum (S)` as function call. But it means 'the sum, which we call S from now on' ... ok.

Comment: thx @PeterCordes, this link brought me to [this hello world example](http://timelessname.com/elfbin/), which is much cooler than those boring wikipedia lemmas :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 1-bit wide integer = boolean value, carry-out has nowhere to go, so **addition simplifies to just XOR**.

---

Fun fact: XOR is add-without-carry.  It's part of implementing a single-bit adder out of logic gates, e.g. a ["half adder"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Half_adder) that has 2 inputs (no carry-in) and produces a sum and carry-out.  (sum = `a xor b`, carry = `a AND b`).  A simple 32-bit adder could be build out of a half adder and 31 "full adders".  Or more adders in parallel with tricks to optimize it for lower latency than a simple ripple-carry binary adders.

Carryless multiplication is a thing in some crypo, where summing partial products is done with XOR instead of normal binary addition.

See also [What is the best way to add two numbers without using the + operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365522/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-the-operator) for a software use of the same idea.

Comment: So the `1 + 1` would result in doing (binary) `1 XOR 1`, which is 0 and `1 AND 1`, which is 1 and these two bits are then joined together, resulting in 01, which is decimal 2, right? What i wonder, how are these actions written in binary notation? What are the binary digits which represent 'do a XOR' and 'do a AND'? Doesnt the computer transform the source code saying '1+1' anyhow into a bunch of 1es and 0es, before it executes these?

Comment: @Nils: Oh, I think I completely misinterpreted the question title and what you were asking.  In the machine code instructions for a real CPU, you'd just see an `add` instruction.  Disassemble any executable (like `objdump -drwC -Mintel /bin/ls`) and you'll see ADD instructions, along with the machine code, for example `83 c0 01` encodes the instruction `add    eax,0x1` for x86-64. as you can see from https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add.  Software that wants to do addition just uses an opcode for a binary addition instruction without caring how it's implemented internally.